What’s on your mind?
You. Yes, you: What’s on your mind?
When you think about the future of the network - years from now - what worries you? What makes you anxious? What do you look forward to? What might make you hopeful?

I’ve spent the last few months thinking about the state of the Stack Exchange network and where the future might take us. My reflections have meandered down many inconclusive pathways, and prompted questions about the network that have no easy or simple resolution. I eventually decided that my long-term aim is to help answer three fundamental questions: Who are we? Where do we want to be? And, what do we need to do to achieve it?
These are large, heavy questions, and they all revolve around a shared sense of common identity and purpose. (I suspect it is uncontroversial to say that the feeling of a common mission has felt somewhat degraded lately.) In many respects, these questions are not mine to answer – but they won’t be answered unless someone stops to ask them. I might as well get us started. But it’s best to take it one step at a time.
“We” might seem a little strange for me to use here. The last few years have not been the most harmonious, I’ll freely admit. So I will clarify. I mean “we” to refer to the three major roles: consumers of the knowledge stored here, those who create and store knowledge, and the people who operate the place itself (not limited to employees), who all together produce the thing we call “Stack Exchange.”

You might be inclined to believe I am preparing you for some specific change, a product release, or maybe a policy shift, and I could hardly blame you for thinking this. But I assure you I am not. I ask out of my own curiosity and a growing restless sensation that tells me questions like these are becoming ever more necessary.
For this reason I feel confident saying there will be more questions and opportunities for discussion in the future. Please do answer, but please don’t rush to answer. You won’t miss your window in the here and now. Stack Exchange isn’t going to keel over and die tomorrow, and there is no hurry: time enough, certainly, for a moment of contemplation, which I would encourage you to take before hurrying to respond.
The answers below should not be a popularity contest, and I’d ask you not to treat them like one. (If I could disable voting, I would.) I really want to know your answer. I want to know what your thoughts are, free from worries about how well it plays to a Meta audience. I know the scripts and boilerplate arguments like the back of my hand. They have merit, but I’m not as interested in rehashing them here (unless you have a particularly useful rendering of them in mind). I’d ask you not to worry about its reception here, and for similar reasons, I’d also ask you not to self-censor too much.
I would like to make explicit that I want to hear from atypical voices on the platform. I want to hear from a wide range of people gathered here. So treat this post as an explicit and open invitation to people who do not normally participate on Meta.  If there’s someone on one of the Stack Exchange sites whose voice is not represented here, please send them a link and encourage them to post.
Finally, while I’d encourage you to read existing answers, I’d also encourage you to post even if it feels like the discussion has already played out. Six weeks from now, I’ll still be interested in your answer.

Please take some time to think. All of your thoughts are welcome, but I’d encourage you to focus specifically on the question at hand: When you think about the future, years from now, what comes to mind? In the long view, what weighs on you, and what gives you hope?
Join me in Chat, if you think the format there will suit your thinking better.

For transparency's sake, I sent this post draft to a small handful of community members in advance of posting it here, with an open invitation to start thinking in advance. The hope in doing so was to open the discussion with a couple longer, considered answers that really help us look a little further than today's issues. But there was no obligation to write, and I don't know when (or if - I didn't ask them to tell me!) those folks will post. So in the meantime, I'd issue you the same plea: before hurrying to answer, know that I want to hear your thoughts, and there is ample time to think.

Dinner.... Oh wait.

Could this post be featured to get people outside the regular meta crowd

For sake of disclosure, I have downvoted this post only because I don't approve the "I sent this post draft to a small handful of community members".  I already daily get the felling that the company is more willing to talk to users (or mods) that have an history of supporting them. Because of this, your choice here sadly only seems to reinforce the "fastest gun in the west" problem - the more answers a post get, the less likely it is that someone will spend time to post their own. Therefore I don't feel the need for a cherry-picked first round of early answers.

@ꓢPArcheon Fair enough, and I did expect some skepticism. I hope you'll understand that I didn't pick a group on the basis of the opinions I expected them to provide. It's just me, coordinating this question. So I can tell you honestly and truthfully that I extended the offer to people I've historically seen offer deeper, thoughtful analyses of questions like these -- not because of opinions they hold. But I acknowledge my own bias. And if you don't believe me when I say that, well, there's nothing much more I can offer. (If you'd like I can share a screenshot of message I sent them, I guess.)

@ꓢPArcheon I was one of the people who was sent this early (I'm still drafting a response). I can tell you with certainty that, while you may think I'm overly defensive of the company, there are at least 3 other people who were invited to take a peek at the post early who I have personally seen as offering a lot of criticism back to the company. Sometimes scathingly so.

Honestly, it doesn't matter what we think. The company's leadership does not care unless it is likely to interfere with their plans to sell our content to get a piece of the AI pie. They are not going to realize until it is far too late that the damage done to the community both directly and from neglect is not something that they will be able to fix by focusing on it after it becomes a big enough problem. This trove of curated content is not the most valuable thing SE has. It's just the only thing SE leadership has the vision to exploit.

Your writing style is still lovely, will you read an answer if I write it?

@bad_coder Thank you, and yes; I've read every answer so far, and I don't plan to stop now. :)

This is a lovely post, and I find it intriguing that it comes from someone who wisely acknowledges, that unlike a CEO, they are not preparing for a specific change.  Maybe someday CEOs will be wise enough to engage in this type of honest communication.  Maybe someday... but as we have learned, CEOs aren't generally the brightest bulbs in the box.

Kudos for asking and then actually responding to the feedback you get.

Please don't vote to close this. It's from a CM who is engaging with MSE, which is great and not something we should shut down. Even if it does ask multiple questions, this type of question from SE staff shouldn't be closed.

What happened to all of the feedback that was gathered under questions tagged community-vp-questions? https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/367463 https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/367713 https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/367906 https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/368208 https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/368588 https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/368835  https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/370015 https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/374725 https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/394117 https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/394772

Those are just the tip of the iceberg among tons of discussions here on meta where people pour their hearts out and write long posts about their thoughts and feelings. There's also posts about moderator councils, and new leadership opportunities and a bunch of other community projects that just fade away with no retrospective on how they went, no lessons learned, and no memory of all the the feedback that the community provided to try to help shape them. Stop asking for vague pointless community feedback as if we've never talked about this stuff before.

@Zoe-Savethedatadump I try not to get to annoyed by it, because supposedly talking about their feelings all the time makes some people feel better. It's incredibly frustrating for those of us who feel better when they have a plan of action instead of being stuck in endless group therapy purgatory. What do we already know? What have we tried? What worked? What didn't work? Do we know why it didn't work? What can we measure? What can we try next?

I've come to the conclusion that the people asking for feedback do not appear to have any power to act upon it so I also don't see the point in reiterating the same messages

@AndreascondemnsIsrael Thanks for your concern - I’m not really “here”; I’m just a cranky old ghost haunting this place until I resolve my unfinished business I guess :) I will probably be here rattling my chains until the company heeds my warning and learns the value of community lest there be no-one to mourn it when it dies…


When you think about the future of the network - years from now - what worries you?

I worry that what you said is true:

Stack Exchange isn’t going to keel over and die tomorrow

But not because it will happen after tomorrow. But it has already happened.
I am directly looking at the company here. After layoff after layoff, I find myself losing hope in the people on "the other side" of the network. The employees and the company. Generally, taken as a whole.
For years, the technical product has been getting somewhat weird, somewhat bad, somewhat incomplete updates. But lately, it feels it has been getting worse. Project after project starts and gets abandoned partway through. We have had things released with an announcement coming hours later of what to expect. When there are already heaps of bugs reported for it. And are never addressed or just partly. The follow-up after something is released and users find it unsuitable is more and more lacking.
It is hard to even pinpoint exactly when this started feeling as more of a problem than just "well, these things happen". Before the layoffs it was already happening, for sure. But after the layoffs it has gotten perceptibly worse. New redesigns or new features or even fixes are done that clearly show whoever is in charge (and that would be multiple people involved) did not actually have an idea what they were redesigning, creating, or fixing. Because they get it wrong.
It is kind of like seeing somebody draw an animal they have never seen but only described. You can squint and maybe see what they were going for. "A yellow horse with black spots, long neck, and horns. Oh, it was supposed to be a giraffe. I can kind of see it." You know - that sort of feeling. Clearly it is not the thing. But it resembles it.
That is becoming increasingly common. Staff have also outright admitted they had no idea how something worked after redesign/fix. When some user pointed out that it is missing some common feature we would take for a given.
Simply put, it feels like whoever is left after the layoffs does not understand the product they have. Neither on what the design was and why (so, technical side of this), nor definitely not on the usage side.
For each new step taken, it seems sometimes there are up to two steps back. And the site is on a very slight downward slope with the occasional slight bump. Like a boring roller-coaster.
And yes, there are things that happen here and there. The Community Asks sprints, for example. They suck, by the way:

I am not trying to be ungrateful. I am trying to say that the company has had the time and resources to address these things multiple times over. Yet it did not. Few things that were implemented were great. But also, few did the step back and forth dance. The ones that need more than 30 minutes - that can have a measurable complexity. The inbox "improvement" from the first sprint? Still not addressed. I hate using the inbox now. And I have to do it every single day. The nonsense that was done with the tag synonyms search. Yeah, it was a yellow spotted long-necked horned horse.
Again, some things were great. Only...I am one of the people who tinkers with the sites. Not as much as others, but I write userscripts and userstyles. Occasionally, even publish them. I know adding an asterisk to the close/delete votes did not take long. I had a userstyle for it. Yes, simple CSS only. The whole infrastructure for determining when you had voted for something was already there. I know it cannot have taken long to just add an asterisk to maybe few places.
And this is what I noticed from the Community Asks sprints. A lot of very low-hanging fruit were picked. I am not ungrateful. I am indifferent. I cannot even get excited for any of this.
I used to be excited. I used to look forward to Stack Exchange trying out a new tech. Maybe even ML, AI - I used to imagine the possibilities. Now any time something is announced, I can only imagine how badly it could fail or how it would be misapplied, how it would be mishandled.
I have lost almost all my faith in the company delivering a product. Which has huge implications as many long-standing users have left over this. Or maybe not "left" but reduced participation by a lot. On one hand, you could say it is over some UX. But the whole thing runs deeper. It also damages the connection with the community.

What do you look forward to? What might make you hopeful?

There are still employees within the company that seem to get it. They use the sites, they do actual conversations. They understand the community.
Like you, Slate. Quite honestly, I decided to answer because you asked this. I might not have written an answer if it was posted by somebody else.
I wish so much that some day I would start thinking of "the company" in similar terms. And not "the company" as one big entity that is clueless, and a handful of employees who are not.

"can we have another fix for a years old thing that would take you 30 minutes" - "no, we have fixes at home" - the fixes at home: https://i.sstatic.net/gDYjjrIz.png

I'm still thinking about this one, probably I'll have more questions with time. But one line stands out to me. "Now any time something is announced, I can only imagine how badly it could fail or how it would be misapplied, how it would be mishandled." It's sticking in my brain because I think it's something we've run into a lot. When ideas have genuine merit, and they're shared with the community, we do get a lot of that back. For now I'm mostly interested in the effect it has, not its internal merit: Ideas, even good-faith ideas, are often seen in their worst believable light.

But "believable" in this case is divorced from what the people who develop the feature intend. There's a reflex: imagine how it can go wrong, assume that will happen, state it will fail. Post-hoc, if something doesn't go quite right, chances are good someone will have proposed it as a failure mode at some point (typically quite hyperbolically so). Very rarely do I see people discuss why one might want it, or really benefit from it. It's not required (doesn't bother me), but its absence is notable. I don't think it can be explained merely by "the ideas are bad." There's something more there.

(Incidentally, I find it a bit funny that you say "I know it cannot have taken long to just add an asterisk to maybe few places." - I was in the room for these discussions, and it actually took quite a lot longer than you might expect. While we know experienced users are fairly likely to get this intuitively, were all users? Would an alternative design help them? What else do we need to do, if anything, to keep it clear? I get it sounds like bikeshedding, but if you serve a million users, confusing just 1% confuses 10,000 people. Actually making the change was the easy part.)

@Slate I understand design takes time. But the implementation? It just feels cheap. Because I know it was. This was the userstyle I had. It...adds an asterisk. Next to the voting button. Like this Close (1)*. Instead of inside the braces like it was implemented on the site Close (1*). Sprint 2 especially had copy edits and configuration tweaks. Again - good it was done. And sure, each was probably discussed. But this could have been done years ago. Over morning/afternoon coffees.

And confusion did happen. People were questioning what the asterisk was. I questioned it. And I was already running the same thing: Vote links looked like this for me: Close (1*)* but there was no indication why. We had  a question on MSO about what the asterisk is almost immediately. It took four hours for an official response. Which also doubled as the announcement.

@VLAZ Oh yeah. The implementation was not expensive or long-running. But viewed as a more comprehensive process, deploying changes is more than "write code" - it's all the discussion and coordination around it. Including a public response explaining what changed, which you point out was delayed, lol. At any rate, it's sort of a side point, I don't mean to detract too much from the meat of your post

On the "low hanging fruit" point: honestly, it's at the point where much of the front facing (HTML/CSS/JS) code could be opened up to community submissions. GitHub with merge requests from community members. Staff review the highly voted ones and merge them. Put the power into the community's hands to run their sites.

Take theming for example. A few years ago there was a whole network redesign, centred around aligning sites to support standardised theming. Much fanfare was made about it, then it was dropped as the eye of Sauron... err.. SE corporate moved on to other things. So why not let the communities in question come up with their own themes? Give us the basic stylesheet and let us put up merge requests for redesigns, for example.

I worry that the business model for the public Q&A network might not be sustainable in the future, and that this will lead to a much bigger conflict between the interests of the company and the community. The entire internet is getting shittier every day, the SE network is one of the few places that still has mostly well-curated content that isn't written simply for SEO or marketing. I worry that complex, difficult questions alone could not sustain the business if the vast majority of traffic vanishes because that need is handled by LLMs and similar tools.
I worry that the community has gotten too rigid in their views on how to enforce our quality standards, and that this might result in sites run by bitter vets that slowly die because no new users take up the work. I don't think there is a fundamental conflict between helping people and creating a library of curated content, but this is a view many experienced members hold.
I worry that the divisions between the community and the company will prevent necessary and maybe risky changes to be done, or done well. The community will likely react badly to many changes and assign ulterior motives to them, and SE will stop listening to the complaints because they will consider them unreasonable. But difficult changes to core systems will not work without community input.
I am cautiously optimistic that AI and LLMs will not be purely a threat to the network but also a chance as there is a niche to fill for authentic and curated human-generated content with high quality.

There's also this thing about VC money which tends to ruin everything by the constant need of increasing profits alone, which is a hilariously misfitting model for public Q&A...

Thanks for this answer. Succinct, but it nails the kind of depth and nuance around root causes I was hoping for. RE your last point - those divisions are ones I feel pretty deeply. Even approaching this question, I know acutely that it will be the first barrier to overcome in holding an open, honest discussion.

I don't think it is necessarily the community that is too rigid, but rather the lack of new tooling or interest in revising how things like permissions work from the company. Catija was finally beginning to spearhead the most meaningful overhaul of how permissions worked on the network (e.g. switching from rep-based to usage-based access) before she was let go, and, surprise--no one from the company has shown any interest in picking up that torch. We have different problems today than we did 10 years ago... but we still have largely the same set of tools as we did 10 years ago.

@TylerH Fwiw, we've (CMs) known about, discussed, and desired to explore decoupling privileges from reputation ever since I joined this company. It isn't a single person's project or a desire that was lost. I would still say we have to do it - reputation has been a bad proxy for knowledge of the various systems for years now (and it was always a proxy). So, on that one, it's less only one person was interested and more focus shifted elsewhere for various other reasons.

@CesarM That's good to hear, and yes it's been a desire of staff and the community in some circles since at least the time I started reading SO (~2013) ...now if only we saw CMs putting time into it, working with the community to flesh out how a system like that would work. It'll never get done if devs have to do all the work on designing and tooling needs, and the community is right over there, waiting to provide ideas/feedback on how such a system like that could look... :-)

@TylerH It's not really hard to implement such a system, that's what Codidact did since literally everyone who was around when that site was started came from here and saw the same problem with rep versus moderator privileges. So it uses a system where you get more moderator privileges the more (user) moderator work you do. Propose a lot of edits and you eventually get full edit privileges etc.

@Lundin and no one uses Codidact. It's what Jeff Atwood predicted when a developer tries to copy Stack Overflow.

@CriticizeSEactionsmeansban I'm not sure what that has to do with this discussion (the moderation system on SE). Why Codidact is struggling with users seems to have everything to do with marketing and little to do with the site design itself.

Necessary preamble: Yes, I am an employee of Stack Overflow. In fact, if you go by original start date, I'm the oldest remaining employee here (but I did spend a few years elsewhere, so I'm not the most tenured). But I'm a simple software engineer who sometimes plays the resident historian, not a decision maker.
I am writing this not because I was asked to. Nobody even pointed me at this question; I just found it on Meta. I also didn't ask anyone for permission to post this.
To be perfectly clear, this is my personal opinion as a member of the community out of which I was hired many years ago, and it's not in any way representing the opinions or policies of the company. I chose to use the word "we" when talking about the company merely because it felt disingenuous to use the third person when in fact I am part of said company.
Finally, I'm writing about Stack Overflow specifically, but most of what I'm writing also applies to the rest of the Stack Exchange network.

The original purpose of Stack Overflow was to build a collaboratively edited repository of programming knowledge.
In that sense, I actually disagree with your (Slate's) comment here, where you say

Fundamentally, we are a pile of questions with a bunch of answers attached to them: the perfect haystack.

Yes, arguably, we are a pile of questions and answers, but in my opinion that is not fundamentally so. The Q&A format was always a means to an end. A couple of points to support that opinion:

We made concrete questions about real-life programming problems the building blocks of the site because it ensured that the collected knowledge is relevant and timely, and the signal doesn't get drowned in the noise of random discussions about anything that could somehow be construed to be programming-related.

Duplicate questions were strongly discouraged, with tools to deal with duplicates built very early on, because a repository of knowledge needs a canonical place with potential solutions to a problem collected in one place, instead of a haystack.

The main purpose of the whole voting system was to make sure that answers can be sorted by what the community thought was the best answers, instead of a cronological list of forum posts.

Jeff Atwood considered Stack Overflow to have reached 1.0 status at the moment when anonymous users were allowed to edit posts, because everyone was supposed to be able to make the answers even better for the next person with the same problem.

When a question was posted, that moment was always supposed to be a tiny seed for what was to become the canonical resource for anyone who might have the same problem in the future. The question itself was important because it was the starting point, but the answers were the pearls. Yes, the original asker should ideally get an answer, but the priority were the thousands of future people who had the same problem, and who now no longer had to ask the question because it was already answered.


So, the original vision was first and foremost to create that archive of knowledge, available for everyone and not owned by any individual entity. Community-curated Q&A were the means to achieve that vision. And it was widely successful.
The founders spent a lot of time thinking about things like community management, often quoting a book on the topic called Here comes everybody. They made decisions about things like gamification, reputation, moderation, and elections. You can argue about each and every decision, and I myself had a healthy amount of disagreement with Jeff on details.
Decisions have consequences, and they will always involve tradeoffs. For example, the strict rules of the site were made to ensure quality and long-term relevance, but they also lead to a culture of rule-lawyering and gatekeeping that we observe on Stack Overflow today, and that give it a reputation of being an unwelcoming place.
But ultimately, the fact that Stack Overflow became an overnight success shows that the decisions seem to have made some sense.
At the time.
And that ⬆️ caveat, to answer your question, is what's on my mind.
Stack Overflow was built for the world of 2008, for a generation of programmers who had often learned programming from books or from trial and error in their IDEs. This was the time that marked the early days of Web 2.0, when Twitter was brand new, and people used the internet much more in a transactional way. Heck, the idea of a web-based chat on the side seemed crazy to many.
But we live in a different time now. People learn new things online. People live online. We're no longer only talking about experienced programmers who learned the ropes elsewhere and come to Stack Overflow for specifc advice. We're talking about generations of programmers who are learning from Stack Overflow, who never experienced a world where Stack Overflow did not exist. People who learn programming from YouTube videos, who discuss their front-end libraries in Discords, who have never installed an IDE because they started their programming journey on Glitch.
(Yeah and there's also the LLM-shaped elephant in the room. I don't want to talk about it.)
It's easy for old-timers like me to dismiss those younger programmers with a giant dose of "you're doing it wrong", but all yelling at clouds is not going to change the fact that the world has evolved, and Stack Overflow has not.
I don't have the answers to what Stack Overflow needs to be like, in order for it to be a home for today's programmers. But I'm pretty sure the answers are different from the ones of 2008.
We need to figure that out, and if there are things about Stack Overflow that no longer make sense in 2025, then let's bring the sledge hammer.
Some people (myself included) are going to be unhappy because those things were important to them. Let's be empathetic with those people, let's allow them their grief, and let's explain to them why we believe we're doing the right thing in order to fulfill that original vision. And let's not do that explaining with a press release and platitudes, but by talking to them eye-to-eye.
Then pour one out, shed a tear, and swing that hammer.
And then build the Stack Overflow of today.

He just wants to be sledgehammer

FWIW, I feel exactly the same way.

@AdamLear And that includes the elephant, I assume.

Sledgehammer, Larkin Poe style https://youtu.be/sL0QYYqz5D8

@balpha Indeed, it does.

I'm not sure I agree, there's been a notable scope shift over the years. For example the site (SO) was never originally meant to be a place where you learnt programming from scratch - rather it was meant to be a place where established ("professional or enthusiast") programmers helped each other. Kind of with the more or less explicit goal to replace CodeProject. Then mid 2010s somewhere it was suddenly an interactive programming tutorial site... which wasn't what the oldest users signed up for. From there it all lost focus more and more, to the point where the site is losing purpose.

@Lundin Which part do you not agree with? The impression you're describing sounds more like you've observed a change in user behavior, rather than to the platform itself. Doesn't that confirm what I'm writing about new generations of programmers and different ways of learning?

@balpha From what I remember this initiative to drop "minimum knowledge required" came from the company and CMs, shog9 & friends, around year 2014. I'm not sure if that was grounded in requests from the actual users of the site or not. At any rate, programmer to programmer interaction is a quite different site goal from one based on teacher to student interaction.

@Lundin I don't recall that, but that doesn't mean you're wrong -- we've had many initiatives over the years. But the controversy about what questions are too simple existed pretty much from the beginning. Jeff and Joel discussed that in podcast 58 (the actual audio isn't there anymore, but it's archived on the IA) -- the origin of the infamous How do I move the turtle in LOGO question.

As always with your answers, it was a pleasure to read and actually helped me a lot towards writing my own answer. Huge thanks!!

I appreciate the answer but I will refrain from voting in either direction because while I agree that something must change you didn't actually say WHAT should be hammered and WHAT should we changed, so I can't really say if we agree on that too.

@ꓢPArcheon Fair enough. I don't even know it myself, and chances are that I'm not gonna like it either. But what's more important to me is that whatever we do, we do it for the right reasons, and that we can honestly explain those reasons.

I fully agree that 2025 is different from 2008 but I don't think it means we all agree on how to build SO new. Being a home for programmers for example sounds more like a social network (Instagram for programmers?). It might be like starting completely new.

@NoDataDumpNoContribution Oh absolutely -- as I said, I myself definitely don't have the answers. And as far as "home for programmers", I just meant that in the sense of "a place most programmers regularly visit", nothing else implied.

Yeah. I don't think everyone agrees on or even has the answer for what needs to change/how Stack needs to adapt, but I think this accurately identifies the identity crisis Stack has found itself in for several years. It needs to adapt, but then the question becomes how it should adapt. The community generally agrees that sticking LLMs/AI where they're not wanted is not the way, but Stack still needs to figure out what to do to bring people back in. Regaining the community's trust is one part of the puzzle, but not the only part.

Refreshing to find someone on the internet who knows what he is talking about. <= That right there is what made SO/SE appeal to me in the first place-filtering out the noise and getting more signal.  I'll have an answer later on, but I want to give a hearty pat on the back to a solidly grounded answer.

What worries me the most is that step-by-step, the company will destroy the core value of the sites and drive away people that come here, day after day, to ask, answer, curate, and engage with others creating wealth of knowledge.
I am worried that experts and learners that are primarily driven by desire to help and share, as well as learn and improve their own skills, will be replaced by ones whose primary desire is collecting some virtual Internet points at all costs.
I am worried that everyone knowledgeable will eventually leave, and that all sites will turn into remnants of old human knowledge covered with AI junk.

quite honestly, for me, my main driver when I was answering questions was because I enjoyed making number go up. I learned things and helped others as a secondary result. I don't think that's a bad thing. I did have the alignment to do it within my understanding of community rules/norms.

@starball It is always nice to see green boxes popping up, and they can provide some incentive when starting. After a while, reputation becomes way less relevant and we want such users to stick around.

Paragraphs 1 and 3 feel closely related to me, or like they're two sides of the same concern. I realize I'm asking you to do a lot here, but I'm curious if there's any core value that stands out to you as at-risk, and how you'd word it if you had to? (Re par 2, it's an interesting thought, but rep's been around since the beginning. Maybe it's gotten worse recently. I'll have to think about that.)

@Slate I am saying that reputation alone serves as some initial incentive. It is without a doubt something that can hook users early on. But, then once you get pass some threshold, reputation is not what makes people come back day after day. Of course, not all users think and feel like that. What I am worried is that ones that care about sites and the knowledge the most and as such are the most valuable contributors, will be the ones that will be driven away first due to company chasing useless AI features.

@ResistanceIsFutile It's interesting - I would've claimed the opposite. Most people don't come for reputation and most don't return just because of it. But it does help people who have made more than a few posts feel rewarded for their contributions, and probably helps them stay. There's some internal research that substantiates this iirc, but sadly I don't think I'll be able to share it here off-the-cuff.

In Lieu of of posting another answer - I'd say in an ideal world, I'd like this to be a place the community that left comes back. There was a social element in 'old' SE that's still around, but not here, and we're poorer for it.

@Slate Most people don't come for reputation and those kind of users are exactly the ones you are bleeding. company is burning the good will with those users and they are leaving. When I am talking about users here I primarily mean experts who know how to answer questions as they are core users that give sites value. Users that ask questions come here because of those who answer. So when answerers leave there are less questions answered and those that remain solely to reap rep are not enough to provide valuable answers and cannot provide that many answers even if their answers are good enough.

My worries aren't really confined to Stack Exchange; I have a broader concern about Enshittification of the parts of the internet I've grown up with and found useful.
Google search is probably the center of my disappointment about the internet lately. You can't find good things from there these days. As others have noted, that often includes not finding Stack Overflow at the top of Google search results anymore. I don't know how much that is SO's fault and how much is Google's.
Instead of useful stuff, most of what rises to the top of search is junk, and even the good stuff is padded with crap to show up in search. That means every recipe page is padded with silly stories no one cares about. If you search for public health information, you're just as likely to find the top results polluted by local clinics and dentists (not even necessarily near you!) who paid a SEO firm, not to mention all the scams selling you on some pseudoscience supplement. Purveyors of honest product reviews are getting crowded out by disguised paid offerings and trusted/familiar brands are being gutted, effectively selling off their reputation without any concern for quality.
This junk all predates the new GenAI craze, but GenAI makes it that much easier to make junk. I don't know if Google will turn their ailing search around, or if they want to; someone who finds what they need right away isn't loading as many Google Ads pages. I'm not finding their competitors' products much better. They're all dealing with a deeper and deeper pile of junk to sort through, and either they don't have their own deep pockets or their own deep pockets come with their own baggage.
Given that it's so hard to find good stuff, it's hard for anyone new to make good stuff: they can't bring the eyeballs to it that they need to grow and survive. What we have left are a dwindling number of individual sites to rely on for decent content. For me, that includes some useful subreddits, it includes Wikipedia, it includes some other more focused Wikis, it includes Stack Exchange, and it includes some more private/local spaces like Discord channels that are either local spaces for a few friends of mine or communities built up around a particular game or modification or software tool.
So, I'm worried about Stack Exchange. I see how catering to business needs often destroys the underlying product. I see how common it is for companies to decide that the most valuable thing they have is their reputation and then subsequently decide that the best way to extract that value is by pilfering it.
Others have held onto the idea that if Stack Exchange does bad enough, some other Q&A will pop up in its place. Maybe that's true, but it's really hard. I think it's gotten a lot harder to bootstrap a good quality site. There already exist alternatives in content (like subreddits) but not really in structure - other Q&A sites are already themselves infested with junk or just don't have enough of a following (sorry Codidact).
I don't think as a company Stack Overflow/Exchange is quite at the pilfering step yet, but it seems like it's coming soon. The new "Jobs" product seems to me like a pilfering move. Other attempts to save the site in the face of GenAI competitors seem doomed to produce a worse GenAI product while abandoning the actual benefits of this one.

Honestly the question about SEO, searchability, and Google results is really salient. To get knowledge into people's hands, you have to a) house knowledge, and b) be discoverable to knowledge-seekers. One without the other does not achieve the end goal. It doesn't matter if the library has every book you need if the address is a well-guarded secret. So if that risks being compromised (or already is), then it's going to be pretty important to think about.

It's interesting to me that you mention Jobs under "pilfering" - I'm sure you're aware it's a service we used to provide in-house, years ago (albeit in a different form). Interestingly, it was not warmly received when it was launched, but its removal was even worse-received. It ended up becoming a highly valued component of the network. It makes me wonder what the word "pilfering" means to you in this context, or maybe more generally what the critical elements of a design are that tip it from "symbiotic" to "pilfering."

@Slate In the sense I'm using it here I'm referring to selling off the trust that exists in a brand. An example might be: I'm a brand known for high-quality refrigerators. I learned in MBA school that I can license my brand name to a low-quality competitor and they can sell low-quality refrigerators at a premium thanks to my brand. I've now sold a brand reputation possibly built over decades for short-term profit. From my perspective, the new Jobs product papers a StackOverflow logo over Indeed, a scraper that represents the worst trends in job search on both sides.

That makes sense @Bryan - thank you for the clarification. In that sense, I can empathize. I guess even if the new version worked as well or better than the old, there might still be something material to the feeling that a public reputation and trust were leveraged to achieve it. Even though I can emotionally see what you mean, I'm still not sure I fully understand the logical difference, even though I know there is one. (Even if it were in-house it'd still leverage reputability and trust to be successful.) I'll have to think about it

that often includes not finding Stack Overflow at the top of Google search results anymore or finding those sites that seem to just be scraped SO questions and answers, but with another design

@Slate Regarding the logical difference between how people look at a home-grown product vs a mostly external product that just has a brand name wrapped around it, it happens in many other business areas too and probably has a bad reputation because it was misused in the past, i.e. more often an inferior version was sold. Not sure why it's like this but just giving away your brand name's good reputation may be an irresistible temptation for a quick buck. Of course the product could be great, but typically it isn't. People feel  their expectations are not meet.

Fortunately, Stack Exchange still provides data under Creative Commons licenses which can be used for bootstrapping.

@CriticizeSEactionsmeansban I'm confident a site that starts by just hosting existing CC content is only one baby step towards a full forward-looking Q&A experience.

I would first answer your questions with a question of my own: before people sink considerable energy into responding to this in meaningful ways, since you mention this is just you asking out of curiosity, what weight is there behind this initiative? If we come to you now with deep, impactful concerns that drive at the root of some existential problem, is anything going to happen to address that problem? Especially if it interferes with other interests by the company's board or leadership direction?
I ask because we already have a bunch of the answers you're soliciting here, strewn about in questions and answers here on MSE or on MSO or other network sites, bemoaning the state of things, highlighting critical bugs in software or in workflow processes that go outright ignored by the only people who can address them: the company. And they are ignored because they don't align with (and in some ways directly conflict with) the company's current vision, which is: cash in on the (freely donated) work of the community to sell data to Google in an effort to make a bunch of money. Instead the only work on the core product (Q&A) anymore is a one-week sprint every few months (which sometimes get canceled anyway) or random UI/design overhauls no one asked for and which break half the site functionality, to boot.
So I guess what worries me about the future is: how bad will Stack Exchange be after <insert number here> more years of soulless abuse of the original purpose of Joel and Jeff's vision (of a high-quality, curated open network of Q&A sites populated by human experts) by owners who not only don't understand but also don't even try to use the product they now control, or listen to their traditional customers (SE communities), instead opting to shift to the business-minded view that the only customers are those who pay, not understanding that it's the other kind of customer (the user base) that made the product and company worth paying anything in the first place.
Jeff and Joel did a great thing with the re-launch of Stack Exchange 2.0 when they licensed all future content under Creative Commons, but the main mistake they made was not making Stack Overflow a non-profit or similar structured business entity. Because it is just a general for-profit corporation, I'm worried they doomed it to a future of ownership by value-extracting MBAs who care about shareholder value and press releases rather than whether the product is any good or the customers are actually served. That's certainly been mostly what we've experienced since the sale to Prosus, and I'm worried that the company will continue along that trajectory. Stack Overflow doesn't need to make lots of money or partner with AI or whatever else. They just need to have a few core offerings like ads, enterprise instances, and job listings (whatever happened to that, eh?) to pay the bills. The company should focus on finding its niche and fitting there for as long as it can, not constantly growing or constantly reinventing itself like toxic MBA/private equity culture demands.

Your question is interesting, and I expected to run into it. The truth is, I'd be foolish to promise you any specific outcome or future on the basis of this post. But I'll tell you why I'm making it: My earnest belief is that, in Stack Exchange, we've built something worth fighting for. If discussions like these are truly locked off forever, devoid of value, then I guess we have to accept that no amount of discussion can ever be productive: best give up now. But if there's something worth preserving here, I have to believe it is possible for us to find a successful pathway and do it.

So you're right, in a specific sense. I'm not expecting anything revolutionary by asking this; the insights we're likely to glean here have probably been said by someone, somewhere, before. (Probably not compiled or framed the way I'm asking here, though.) And even if it were totally new, I'd have to expect that this specific question won't end up being "the right one" to ask. It's exploratory. Thankfully, we don't have to stop asking questions after just the one. The rest of your answer is valuable, and is something I'm going to have to think more about before I have all that much to say.

A big part of the scenario you wrote about in your closing paragraph hinges on one key thing: the company being able - in your words - "to pay the bills" versus an endless search for ever-increasing profits. I can also see hints of that permeating throughout the text. There are two - distinct - and important questions from it that I believe are worth exploring: 1) What makes you believe that the actions taken are a result of chasing ever-increasing profits 2) What sort of actions would you believe you'd be seeing if the goal was to pay the bills? (+1 comment with details on the questions)

It may seem that the answers to those are "exact opposites", but I believe that is likely too simplistic, so I'd encourage you (and other folks, if they so wish) to explore it more than just "well, we wouldn't be seeing X" but rather the positive of "we'd be seeing Z".

Thanks, TylerH, for yet again phrasing pretty much what I have in mind, in far more detail and much better style than I'd ever have the skill or patience for. @CesarM I know you didn't ask me, but practically nothing the company's done in the past years has felt like it considers the community of curators a stakeholder. Any positive step ends up looking a lot like a diversion tactic, like the community sprints that seem like low-effort buffers to soften terrible news. (cont.)

Between the galactic amounts of VC money paid for the company, the constant push of arbitrary KPI improvements (which usually end up making the platform objectively worse for existing curators) and top management's apparent infatuation with the ruthless AI ecosystem (again in stark contrast with the curation goals) it's hard to see anything other than profit being the motivator. Every now and then plenty of old-timer curators provide the company with a list of "THIS IS WHAT WE'VE BEEN ASKING FOR FOR MANY YEARS". We'll start looking for true interest when the company starts tackling those.

Consider, why wouldn't you want to do a community asks quarter? Whats more important than that. And why is that more important?

@user1937198 I am not really sure where that question comes from. The answer didn't tackle "community asks" sprints at all. And I don't think anybody suggested devoting a full quarter to it. But wherever that quarter comes from - same thing with the sprints. We shouldn't need specific times for long-standing issues to be fixed. We need long-standing issues to be fixed all the time. And not have new issues that become long-standing either. So also fix issues. A normal workflow: don't release broken functionality, fix important things early, finish projects. Not to delay these arbitrarily.

@VLAZ It wasn't really to you so much as a response to Cesar Ms comment about 'paying the bills'. And its exactly as you said, it should be all the time, but it isn't. Its one sprint a quarter. So whats happening in the rest of the quarter, and why is that more important?

@CesarM Andras already told you why many fell like monetization of the network knowledge content it the only goal for the company, and by this I mean Prosus. But I want to ask the opposite question instead. If it is not a goal of profit that made Prosus buy the network, then what was it? Believing in that "making the internet a better place" thing Jeff had when creating the site? Because in that case I would question... wouldn't turning Stack Exchange in that independent NO PROFIT entity many dream of be the best proof they never intended to use the network just for profit?

@CesarM "1) What makes you believe that the actions taken are a result of chasing ever-increasing profits" Deals with Google and other companies to sell our content for AI using every possible avenue for injecting AI into the site. Also, deals with shady job boards to sell our jobs/user data and trade on the Stack Overflow brand.

@CesarM "2) What sort of actions would you believe you'd be seeing if the goal was to pay the bills?" The kind of things that the company was doing before selling the company to a private equity form. A paid product for enterprise users to spin up their own instance of SO, hosted or on-prem. Ads markets that have far more value to customers because they're required to be topical, high quality, and are vetted by people. (1/2)

@CesarM A real, proper jobs market like the old SO Jobs that connected real, genuine hirers with experts in their fields (this was going OK for Stack Overflow but for some reason was never expanded to other subject-matter network sites. WTH?!). Stack CVs was a good start as well that could've easily been monetized with a bit of additional work (turned fremium), and expanded to other network sites as well. (2/2)

@CesarM I have a degree in business administration and have managed small to huge teams so I know fairly well that it's not exactly an "easy" task, both in execution or in patience, but it's one that I think is doable with the right structure and commitment to the ideal that is Stack Overflow/Stack Exchange. But it's exceptionally clear to anyone paying attention that the current company's ownership and top leadership is not interested/does not share that same commitment to said ideal. Their interest is in money, like every other company in the world acquired by a private equity firm.

@CesarM "I'd encourage you (and other folks, if they so wish) to explore it more than just "well, we wouldn't be seeing X" but rather the positive of "we'd be seeing Z"" If you'll notice, folks on Meta largely aren't asking the company to make right by reinventing the wheel. The lion's share of what folks are asking for is to just stop making things worse, because things were OK before. So I apologize but we have already well explored what the positive things are that we'd be seeing: just look at what we had pre-2019 and go back to that.

@CesarM If you want a specific example, here's one that can be started on immediately: have the current developers familiarize themself with their core product again. Require devs to use the site for some period of time before they're allowed to touch the codebase. That means ask some questions, write some answers, suggest some edits, do some reviews, synonymize a tag, handle some flags, etc. for several weeks. This can be done in your sandbox/test environment on content that's already been handled/done on production, if you wanna make it easy and control for the ideal/proper outcome.

@CesarM Another thing that would be better: go back to posting changelogs whenever you push changes to the site. Devs or CMs used to always make a post or answer somewhere that listed line items to the best of their ability of what was changed whenever a new version was rolled out. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59445/recent-feature-changes-to-stack-exchange used to be maintained by staff. Now it's maintained by community users doing their best at guessing/keeping up with changes.

@CesarM A third thing that would be better: please for the love of , stop making changes to the markup/layout/design of the site unless there's a bug report on Meta that you're specifically addressing. If there isn't one, post one yourselves so the community can A) weigh in on whether it's a good idea/problem B) provide potentially better solutions, and perhaps most importantly C) have a heads up as to when a change might be coming that absolutely wrecks the user scripts they rely on daily to use the site.

@AndrasDeak--СлаваУкраїні I did say "and other folks" so thank you for answering (sincerely). I do want to explore a bit further! The things you mentioned (AI, KPI improvements, not having curators as stakeholders) are examples of things largely viewed as bad. But I am still curious how they directly translate to "endless chase of ever-increasing profits". Profit being the motivator is present whether it's case A or B (ever-increasing or enough money to pay the bills). Much of the sentiment I read around this topic seems to indicate folks believe it's A rather than B, though. (cont)

But companies in scenario B are also chasing profits, for different reasons. Many examples of Enshittification (Bryan's answer) are of companies trying to get out of losing money. Many of the media companies cited on the topic of bad reviews (Also Bryan's) were also trying not to die because they weren't turning profits. So, both A and B companies do things perceived as bad or anti-consumer. However, from TylerH's answer, it seems to matter why they were doing it (if A or B). I am still curious what actions you'd expect to see from us if the case were B.

Is doing the things in the "What we've been asking for for many years" list a sign of that? I'm not sure how it is if so. I understand why it would be a good sign for interest in curators/community, but not why it would reflect a company interested in making money to survive. Thus, I return to the question: Does it matter if it's A or B the motivation? If not, does it change anything about what TylerH said? And what would a company in scenario B be expected to be doing instead of what, in yall's view, puts us in scenario A?

@SPArcheon The comments above are all a part of a response to your comment, too. But I want to add that "making the internet a better place has never been the only goal. The company was founded as a for-profit company. There has always been a desire to monetize the network, not to be burning VC cash. That desire was likely reflected in the valuation the company was acquired for, which translates to how much the previous Stockholders got paid for their stocks. There seems to be a difference in using it just for profit and also for profit. But that returns us to the questions above.

@TylerH it's worth saying that the comments above were drafted before I read your comments, so they aren't informed by what you wrote. But I will read it and write more comments! :D

@TylerH, thanks. Those are direct answers to the questions, and then you added a fair bit of suggestions on top of them. I think what you wrote makes sense, and feels (to me) like it accurately describes why the assumption is that the case is A rather than B (see above). It does all hinge, though, on assuming that the things being done before by themselves generated then, and could generate now, enough money to create profit. It's worth having that explicitly said I think. But overall, I'm happy with the answer you've given (if you or anyone wants to chime in more, feel free!).

(One last addition): from what you wrote, it seems to be that the major point of contention isn't actually if it feels like it's A or B. The major point of contention is that that's what you see as most prominent. Your (added) suggestions at the end that aren't a direct answer to the questions are all in line with changing things that are done, not why they're done. So it seems to me that the end conclusion is what is done matters more than why - and the feeling of A is an added way to express frustration but isn't because it's A. A company could be doing the same things if it were B.

@CesarM I'm not entirely sure I'm still following, so apologies if this happens to be mostly a non sequitur. "Only profit matters" vs "just trying to pay the bills" is an XY situation. Much like how we treat homework on SO. It's not the homeworkness per se that's an issue, but the quality of the question. A good homework-motivated question doesn't actually make it obvious that it's a homework question, because it's just a good question, and then nobody actually cares if it's homework. I see this problem similarly. Nobody actually cares if the company only chases profits. (1/2)

But the way current top management imagines KPIs doesn't include maintaining the knowledge base ecosystem that is (well, used to be) Stack Overflow. So by optimizing for their profits without optimizing for the actual platform they are trying to monetize they are constantly harming the platform. And this is what we perceive as "only money matters". A non-evil company "just trying to pay the bills" would make sure the cow is fed and healthy before trying to start an AI cheese empire. So it's obviously not about the actual motivators, just the symptoms we see. (2/2)

@AndrasDeak--СлаваУкраїні that's actually a great-sequitur! That's mostly the same conclusion I arrived at, yes. So we're understood :)

The way I'm thinking about this A/B question is not so much about "lots of profit" versus "just getting by", but about what is the tool and what is the goal. Do we want to make money in order to support the creation and maintenance of the platform and the repository of knowledge? Or do we want to create and maintain those in order to make money? Over a short time frame, these two are hard to tell apart, because on a basic level, they are not even incompatible. But over a longer period, they will lead to differences in decision making.

Indifference
This is not meant as some hyperbole based on recent events. Well, there is a bit of pouting perhaps, but that is really just the icing on the cake. When you ask me to think about the future of the network, years from now...

[radio static]

Now, hold on rolling your eyes for a second while we stroll down memory lane...
You see, SE (actually, SO initially for me) was an idea to invest in. Building a library of knowledge and all that. Using a library of knowledge, just to get that point its often-missing spotlight. Yeah, that good feeling when you are finally given a broom because you are trusted to help keep the place tidy behind the scenes.
That warm feeling of familiarity when you open SO at 10 PM, find an answer to your problem and realise you already upvoted it a year ago. Because SO got your back no matter how forgetful you are. Because on SO, DenverCoder9 does share their wisdom.
This spark is gone.
I could (and did) come up with things that worry me, that make me anxious, that I might look forward to, or that might even make me hopeful. But those are, to be completely honest, all technical thoughts. Whether AI makes SE obsolete, how the community might change, licenses and acknowledgements and what it means to be a library and how that could evolve and yada yada yada.
But none of that is "on my mind". It is in the spreadsheet-land of my head, the tinkering-with-a-challenge section, the trying-to-crack-a-puzzle domain. A metaphorical piece of paper that you know had some interesting scribbles on it but if you lost it, well...
What is "on my mind" is... meh.
SE losing the space AI race? Well, too bad, what else is on? The community duking out an epic battle of curationists versus helpdeskians? Welcome to the internet. The ultimate solution to acknowledgment of intellectual impact in an age of evolving rationality of information provenance given coevolving diffusion of knowledge dominion? Sounds like fun (NOT). An irreplaceable vault of knowledge jeopardised by the whims of modern techno-society? Welcome to the internet, again.
What is on my mind? On my mind is "I don't care".
And this is worrying me about the future of the network. Because the network does not run on "I don't care". Because I am decently sure I am not the only one who has to admit to themselves "Actually... I don't care".
But at the same time, it makes me hopeful. Because, you know, for every other swing of the axe to the network by SE inc or vocal members of the community or the public opinion or people silently quitting... I don't care anymore.
‍♂️

So shines a good take in a weary world....

Contrariwise - what would convince you to care?

@JourneymanGeek That's the problem though - once someone who was highly engaged reaches the "meh" point, it's too late to fix. Even this question asking us to really dig deep and think about the future of the network is counter-productive IMO. Wait, SE wants me to expend the effort to tell them yet again what the problem is when I'm exhausted from years of trying to communicate that there was a problem? I'm supposed to think of ways to make me re-engage? Frankly, it's a miracle I still check in here at all.

Indifference is sort of an interesting answer to this question. I'd almost be tempted to say it's a category error. There are two kinds of "indifferent": those who are disillusioned to the extent that they no longer have any desire to participate, and those who have given up on the company but still care about the general mission in some respect (and often do still participate). I don't think we can treat these two groups as equivalent.

The former group are so indifferent that they no longer care to speak at all. By definition, they have no positive role to play in deciding what the future of the network will be, nor should it hold any interest to them. Their absence may be felt (perhaps at times acutely so), but the future of the platform probably isn't going to be discussed, established, or led by people who are indifferent to the outcome. The latter group, indifferent to the actions of the company but who do care about the community's mission, are not the same in this respect. That group's voice matters tremendously.

@Slate Wow. I honestly didn't expect such a strong and definitive rejection of people. That's the recipe for survivorship bias.

I wouldn't really say it's rejection: If you're posting here, you're almost definitely not in that group. (It also doesn't make me happy when people grow indifferent, and I'm not glad to see anyone go.) But if we're thinking about the future, then it's a question of who's here, and who cares: people willing to contribute in some small way towards shaping the future of Stack Exchange, if only by sparing their thoughts every now and again. Those will be the voices with an active role to play. And by definition, such people are not indifferent. They care about something.

(So like, for clarity's sake, I should say that the opinions and values of the people who have left remain as important as they always were. Really, the opinions of all people who do not speak and do not join are important when considering what a comprehensive, effective future for the platform might look like. They won't be shaping the future with their own hand, but the future should be shaped with them in mind. And the moment someone decides to join in, they jump the line from indifference to action. That option must always stay open.)

@Slate With respect, and being fully aware that I’m a grumpy old wet blanket… What makes you think discussion is going to shape the future? No-one involved has the power to act. The community has earnestly shared their hopes and worries and ideas over and over. You can’t crowd-source a vision. The root problem is the community rejects the company’s current vision and there is no leader who can credibly offer an alternative. There’s no point fighting when there’s no hope of changing anything. Yet another thread of insight-gathering just reinforces my belief I can in no way affect SE’s path.

@ColleenV I started this discussion because I see the potential for opportunity to bring about real change. But I can't make a promise about what will come of all this. So you're welcome to be as skeptical as you'd like of that: God knows you've reason enough to be. What else can I say? We've had a hard few years. If I'm proven wrong and an opportunity never materializes, I don't think I'll regret having done my best. I would dispute that this thread simply rehashes what's already been said, though: the number of new ideas I've seen (and new variants of old ideas) is considerable.

@Slate It's OK that you haven't seen the cycle enough times yet to know how this will end. There will be a lot of discussion, and good points made and absolutely nothing will be done. I would be less skeptical if you had at least attempted to look at what has gone before, but for some reason these well-meaning efforts always start from scratch as if the prior discussions are somehow obsolete even though many of us from a decade ago are still here. I don't think this is the best you can do, and I don't mean that to be disparaging, just that there has to be a different approach to try.

@ColleenV I've been employed here for over three years and I moderated the network for seven years before that. Trust me; I've seen a lot.

As a staff moderator and veteran community member, you have more insight and power than many of the community. There has to be a better use of your time and energy than leading yet another insight-gathering discussion that has a big asterisk that it's probably unlikely anything could come of it. Sorry that I'm completely burnt out on this, but it's really discouraging to see the same thing happen over and over and over and everyone just hoping it will end differently because we all really miss when things were better.  What insights from the past 10 years are just getting rehashed here again?

@ColleenV I'd be happy to talk more about it in chat if you'd like; not to shut down the conversation, I just feel it would be more productive than trying to answer that question in a comment thread this deep. It's a good question to ask, and an emotionally fraught one. For now, I'll leave it at this: One way or another, I hope we can get outcomes that do not disappoint.

@Slate I think this answer sums up what the big majority of the long term users feel. And I really don't see how "disillusioned" versus "given up about the company" are two different groups. I gave up on the company many years ago. I still participate mainly because of interest in the topics themselves, not because of some grand mission. It's just something you do to kill time, kind of like watching that TV series which is actually quite bad but you need to relax and kill half an hour before dinner. ->

I'm happy to do the same on different sites, this particular network has no special place and could get burned to the ground for all I care. If I'd be passionate about some sort of mission, I'd go do that on a non-profit open source site, not in the presence of yet another soulless, US-based tech company which blatantly obviously does not care about anyone or anything except profits. There's always what the company says and what the company does. Which is why communicating with such companies is a huge waste of time, it doesn't matter what they tell you. Look at what they are doing instead.

@JourneymanGeek Sorry for not responding earlier, and already sorry for not responding directly. I had to think about this for quite a while. Ultimately, I have come to the conclusion there is no answer in the direct sense. The meta-answer is that what it would take for me is that SE stops asking such questions. (Now, please stick with me again for a second.) To skip right ahead, being occasionally included in directional and technical decisions is nice, but by and large I expect SE Inc to, pardon the french, to flambé know themselves what they are doing. Here's the thing: [...]

[...] As much as the mud wrestling on meta is entertaining every now and then, it's really not why I am here. The same way I don't expect having to tell the cook in a restaurant how to prepare my food, I don't expect having to tell SE Inc how to prepare my Q&A platform (and for that matter, no daily quasi-anarcho-democratic-legislature with other patrons, either). Sure, I will let Giovanni from down the road know how I liked his attempt at a Tarte Flambé, but if it turns into a five year self-driven market analysis with an occasional mud cake for good measure, I'll just not care anymore. [...]

[...] If Giovanni does a grand reopening with a completed concept, maybe I'll drop by. But if he tanks and Raj moves in to offer something completely different I won't mind either.

I mean, that's entirely reasonable - and I'd say a good answer, which is less "I'm not sure" than you think, beats a quick one.

@Slate Thinking about the question by Journeymen Geek got me thinking about why what you wrote just rubs me the wrong way. Really, I feel the response is pretty much the same (suppresses urge to dupe-close) though reformulating it may be worth it: I have really come to hate this unspoken expectation that one has to contribute on meta and similar. Somehow, "caring about the mission" has shifted from actually participating in the content on main, to endless and frankly often vile shouting matches on meta. I’ve just now marvelled at a history lesson of just what the "rude/abusive" flag means.

[…] If even such a tiny flag requires archeology through meta, at some point indifference is a coping mechanism. Right on the same page there was the n'th pushy can-we-use-AI-please-question with all the drama rehashed again and again, with another disjoint link collection for everyone to please dig through. If even such a well-discussed topic just doesn’t end, at some point indifference is a coping mechanism. I really can’t say here whether the problem is the community or the lack of guidance by the company, but whatever it is it’s not working.

[…] So if we are back here, and I see you write well-meant words how posting means not being indifferent, and being able to join back in, and shaping the future, and all that: This is actually a horrible outlook. This is exactly why I have become indifferent to so much here. Rehashing all the stuff, scratching every itch, pointlessly participating: At some point indifference is a coping mechanism.

I'd like to thank you for asking us these questions. They're really important ones to re-ask every once in awhile with a project as old as Stack Exchange is. The world's changed a lot in these last few years, and the network's changed right along with it. People come and go, features rise and fall, but this massive encyclopedia of knowledge is still here, and still widely useful.
I'm going to try answering the "big", core questions. I anticipate that I'm going to say things that are either flat-out wrong, or that you disagree with. I fully expect to miss the mark at times. I imagine this may be because I haven't been around here nearly as long as a lot of others. I still want to throw them out there.
Oh, and let's get rid of a few readers now. You can just stop reading and downvote if you disagree with this statement, because after a lot of reflection, I don't personally respect this line of thinking anymore:
Stack Exchange, Inc. is not evil.

Who are we?
We're a large, multicultural arrangement of users working together, knowingly or unknowingly, towards the betterment of an impossibly large encyclopedia of Q&A-style knowledge. We believe in a self-regulating system that empowers its users to act like stoneshapers, carving away at rock until it resembles something worthwhile to look at.
... No. That's a bit of an antiquated definition, isn't it? Much as we'd like for it to remain as it used to be, this place has grown to be far bigger, incorporating the interests of far more than just a core userbase. You're a software company whose flagship product of public Q&A no longer feels like its flagship product, because you've added more products to support. We have to expand our definition to include the creation and maintenance of software that's at the benefit of your sponsors via Collectives, your customers via Teams and OverflowAI, and your shareholders. That's a long list of people you need to do right by. So much so that... Sometimes, it feels like you do so at the expense of the community that's been there since the start. The community that spawned when Stack Overflow was tears in Jeff and Joel's eyes; where the words "Build it and they will come" were first floated. That public Q&A community has changed too, though. It's grown, shrunk, expanded and contracted in interests and desires, flared up during controversy and quelled during times of ease. It's acted as your contributors, your feedback mechanism, your research audience, your QA testers, your moderators, your confidants, and... Dare I say, at times, your friends.
We're more than we ever were, now. That makes things challenging. For us, and for you.
Where do we want to be, and what do we do to achieve it?
Where do you want to be, Stack Exchange? I don't think you've told us lately. I'd love for you to answer that question. You've, in a roundabout way, been telling us what you want to do to achieve it with some of your actions, but sometimes that feels... Off to us. Decisions and product movements that just don't feel right. When you do state a goal for a change, it sometimes feels like you either aren't working towards that goal, or like what you're doing may even run contrary to that goal. Maybe that's because we don't know what the heck you're trying to get at.
I really think that we seriously just don't see your vision, and when we point out issues with what you're planning to do, we don't feel as heard as we feel we should be. Were we all on the same page, maybe it would make more sense. Instead we have to guess, and that leads us down toxic, and sometimes conspiratorial, lines of thought. I hate being there. I hate listening to others follow those thoughts. It feels shortsighted, rude, unproductive, and pointless. But how can we be less shortsighted when we don't know what your vision for this place is? Tell us what you're trying to do, how you're going to do it, and why. Lay it all out for us in a way that truly unveils what your core goals are, and try and listen to us when we point out that what you're doing runs afoul of that goal. We're not as unreasonable as you might think.
One thing you're not lacking in here is a long line of people who want to see you succeed. We differ in our views of what success looks like because we seem to have an entirely different finish line than you do. My Dutch moderator colleagues have repeatedly mentioned that they worry their Dutch bluntness can come off too strongly at times, but I urge you, as I would urge you with all feedback, to pierce through that bluntness to the core of their message, because it's so often what needs to be said or considered. I value their input deeply, no matter how well it's dressed.
The community, if I dare to represent it here, wants to move towards a Q&A product that empowers its contributors to make the content here the best it can be, with as many well-meaning users contributing as it can. We want to be the place that people go when they want answers to their questions, feel rewarded when they get those answers, and feel safe in the knowledge that they've been vetted by helpful humans. We want new users to be informed of how to best fit in with the established norms and guidelines, and feel welcomed into the space. We want the content on the network to be human-verified at a minimum, accurate, and helpful.
To get there, we want the public Q&A product to receive a lot of community-sourced attention from SE on the technical issues we've been asking for for years. We haven't even begun to consider the "societal" problems we have because we're so distracted by all the technical problems we'd like you to address. I hope that was one of the takeaways when Phillippe asked his magic-wand question, because he explicitly asked us to err away from technical asks, and yet 90% of the responses there were technical asks.
What does the future look like, years from now? What weighs on you?
To be honest? Minus the recent AI... uh... stuff... and the potential for that to leak onto the site... For the most part, I would imagine the network looks the same as it currently does. Y'know... That worries me a lot. I'm really worried that not enough meaningful change is going to come between now and, say, five years from now. Whether that's a result of a lack of resources or a lack of direction is unclear. What gives me this impression is a "Two steps forward, three steps back" feeling at times. That isn't meant to make you feel as though your efforts are worthless, it's just a feeling that I have. I'll readily admit it may not be fully rational.
I'll take a moment to mention something that weighs on me a little, and it's related to the  Community Asks sprints. These sprints are fantastic and I'm really happy to see some old, long-requested, low-engineering-lift asks are being completed by you guys. I will never stop giving you credit for doing them. So... Why does this weigh on me? Because the nature of it makes me feel
(rightly or wrongly) like our Asks aren't otherwise being prioritized. We've got a long laundry list of technical adjustments that we'd love to see. You guys don't have the engineering bandwidth to tackle a lot of them, and I completely understand that. But when we have all of these outstanding asks and your resources go towards extremely unpopular features that we didn't ask for and/or gave feedback about how poor an idea it was/is, it feels really bad.
I'll toss some recent examples out there not to be mean and punch down on you, but because a lot of the feedback on them involves a bunch of genuine confusion* about the choices made, which points back to my previous point about how either your goals are miscommunicated to us or your choices in pursuing those goals are misaligned:

Homepage updates for logged-in users (Removing HNQ?, A proposal to mass-edit the tag wikis to account for the change)
Tag hover experiment wrap-up ("Everything about this is backwards")
The most recent Discussions announcement ("What purpose (do) they serve", "It's time to admit Discussions have failed", and this call to stop moderating it because it doesn't have the bare minimum the community needs to support it)

Now let's un-minus that recent... (sigh) - Generative AI stuff... Ugh, I'm seeing AI absolutely everywhere nowadays. It's in my browser, my favorite websites, my operating system... My email service, if you can believe that. Each iteration that's presented to me across the internet, and I promise you I am giving them an honest try, is marginally helpful at best. So many of these applications seem like they could've just been a feature that relied on very few metrics instead of some LLM. All of that primes me not to like it when I see even more of it, but believe me when I say I'm trying to keep an open mind.
Rant aside, let's talk about AI and SE. I'll warn you, I fear I may have written the following a bit unkindly. Not very mod-like, eh?
Since its explosion, you've loudly and proudly been saying you want to try and be a huge advocate for ethical AI, and you've tried relentlessly to get AI on the public platform. You're even putting it in the SG for crying out loud, the SG being something I was so happy with I hopped on with Ben Popper and basically did PR for it. I stand by everything I said in that podcast, but your reckless abandon to pursue AI for the sake of AI is turning me off (the network) really hard. You may think your foray into AI isn't reckless. That it isn't just putting it on the site for the sake of putting it on the site. But that's how it feels to us. Cutting past our reactions to that is going to be extremely difficult.
So obviously when the Answers Bot leak happened, I just... Got sad, I guess? I say this all because SE is the place I go to for human-generated content that's worth reading to help me with a problem I might have. If I wanted AI, I'd go somewhere that has AI. You've heard this before, so let me just carry on.
In the response to the AI bot leak, Philippe says that the main reason for this work is to prepare for a future LLM that is, and I'll exaggerate to the extreme here partly because I'm having fun and partly because I feel like it may demonstrate my point, "The Almighty Understand-er of All Questions that Can Answer Everything Accurately".
Let's assume that's an achievable goal. Let's assume that there will one day exist an LLM that's accurate and "good enough" to pass the smell test of an expert on any given question (because that's one of our bars for participation, by the way!) What the heck use will SE have then? Why would I want to come to a site for a human-written response to an issue when I can just ask the LLM in this futuristic dreamscape that's near perfect and remove the step of looking at SE? This is likely a bit of a shortsighted conclusion, but ultimately you're creating the on-ramp for the kind of content that would herald... Your own obsolescence? Kinda? That's probably stretching it a bit, but assuming we one day have an LLM that needs very little human review... What then?
All of this has been framed from a technical perspective; how the site will function and appear. What about from a social perspective? How does the relationship between the company and the community look five years from now? Do users feel like their asks are being met? I don't have true answers to these hypotheticals. All of it deeply depends on company direction and the world changing around us. Will we continue to squabble about (in our view, half-baked) features? Will we still feel unheard about some things, but heard and respected in others? Will we still have conspiratorial thoughts about you guys killing the data dumps?
What worries you?
I'm worried that the community will never be able to trust you guys again. Not fully, anyway. Like I mentioned earlier, there are folks who are "black-pilled" (warning, Urban Dictionary link) on Stack Exchange. They're convinced that the network can never be where they view it can/should be. They're under the impression that you guys are doing good things to shadow the bad. They're convinced you don't care, that you're going to kill the data dump, that you're going to force AI down our throats, and that you're stealing our data and selling it to the highest bidder.
I don't like to think that way. I like to think that you have far more nuanced motives. But what worries me is that, if these kinds of negative sentiments are mainstream... What the hell is the point in continuing? If we've completely discarded the assumption of good faith, how can we ever hope to move forward in an environment where the community is meant to be at the center of everything you do?
What gives you hope?
The people.
What I mean by that is, there are a bunch of people who really try their best to make this site the best it can be in whatever avenue of greatness they can leverage. Their efforts are felt and appreciated, even if they aren't outwardly acknowledged.
After the Strike debacle, I was hopeful that things could start to repair and improve. I will say that on several fronts, SE has been more communicative when they have the time to do so. Becoming a mod here let me take a peek into the Mod Team and the TL, and in the recent months (in comparison to the months prior to that that I had read the backlog of), staff have made several posts that really dropped the veil on how things work internally, the current status of some things, and a few other posts that were just really genuine. I really, really value those posts. Even as I write this, Slate wrote a really illuminating post (mod-only link) that I really hope makes it, in some form, onto Meta not only because it's important to the network, but because it was a very genuine and informative response from an employee. I wish I could talk about it here. I'm sorry for mentioning it when I can't.
Further, after my appearance on the SO podcast, Philippe sent me an email. He said he listened to every word I had said, and I believed him, because he went on to point out several bits from the rough cut of the podcast. He then offered an open line of communication, stating that if there ever was anything that I felt needed pointed out to him, I should do so through e-mail, and he promised he would read it. While I'd say that I'm a bit sad (and maybe a little disappointed) to see that Philippe doesn't participate around the network as much as when he became community VP, I can tell in my communications with him that he really does care about the network. I wish he showed us that side of him more often. Even still, that genuine love for what works here gives me hope.
I love seeing questions like these. I love it when employees talk openly about what they're working on. I love being involved in the process of crafting network greatness, because I feel heard and respected. My involvement with the SG beta showed me what community-driven development could look like, and I haven't seen a similar effort since. I want more of that.
So... There are really good people here who work to try and make this place great. Using that drive in a manner that serves the community (yeah that's hard to put a target on, I know) is your best path forward.
I'll close this out with a thank you to those who read through everything, especially SE employees who made it through. I wrote entirely too much, and probably said a bit that you disagree with, but you read it anyway. Thank you for listening.

@Spevacus What has led you to believe that stack exchange inc.  Is not evil?

@Starship A few things. 1) The assumption of good faith. 2) The continued communication the company participates in with the community. Part of that is the communication mods get, and I recognize that's not something most people see, but know that they do listen and act on our feedback. Another part of that is, even though it took awhile, comprehensively answering touchy community questions. 3) The people. The staff that makes up the company genuinely cares, and they give us their best when they can. -- What makes you think SE is evil?

It’s an assumption of goof faith, not a belief to be held against all evidence. The communication and listening to feedback we (as regular users) get is not on the actual big issues, generally. Fixing a minor bug is great but I’d rather they fix stack exchange from becoming a dead ai filled trash can. Admittedly I can’t know what goes in behind the closed diamond doors, but what sounds good about “we only care about what a few users think and ignore and keep everyone else in the dark”. I do believe that the staff care, when I am referring to SE being evil I mean management, continued….

Who actually makes the important decisions. What makes me think SE is evil is a years long pattern of ignoring the community and destroying the site

@Starship Would you mind clarifying what "evil" and "destroying the site" mean here? Maybe chat is a better place for this? Slate set up a room for this sort of thing if that's better.

I've read through this a couple times now, and... I think it's gotten less attention than it deserves, honestly. This answer is really good. It covers almost everything that's been on my mind over the last year, and especially the last few months. It's long, but damn, I've read it three times and I'm still thinking.

I think you might be the first person who's explicitly named the complexities in running multiple side-by-side products with different communities, and the implications that has for how the platform feels like it's being run. It has a parallel on the platform, too: network sites felt neglected waaaay back in 2015 - like they were only getting Stack Overflow's hand-me-downs. But now there's a suite of products.

"Where do you want to be, Stack Exchange? I don't think you've told us lately. I'd love for you to answer that question." is a nice inversion tbh. You may be right - we've articulated bits and pieces of a vision in certain places, but have we shared anything that feels empathetic and reasonable to users as a general platform vision? Not just what we hope to change, but who we are, and where we're going? I'm not sure we have. Maybe that's a vacant need. Even if we've posted it, I get the same feeling - so I'll do some digging and see what I find...

To respond to at least one piece of it, I can say that the "black-pilled" (don't like the term, I'll call it extreme nihilism) folks worry me too. But the flipside is that I think there's surprisingly little to do about it. Some people are going to take that the wrong way, but it's true. Extreme nihilism shuts down dialogue completey: You can't force people to think you're ever honest when they're in that frame of mind. You can't appeal to them. You can't converse on neutral ground, exchange new ideas. Even the good things are probably just cover for worse things to come, after all. (1/2)

Success then depends on dialogue with people who are not extreme nihilists. And... here's the thing. Those people absolutely exist. Extreme nihilism is conspiratorial and all-encompassing, and that makes it a big-tent explanation for any event or occurrence. Any more nuanced view is quieter. What I'm saying is, nihilism may be loud, but people who espouse balance are more common. I've spoken with a lot of people across the platform, and I'm firmly convinced they exist everywhere. And they're the ones that carry the torch forward. (2/2)

(And I don't mean that to imply reckless optimism or naivete. People who are not "extreme nihilists" have all manner of viewpoints on the platform and the action we've taken, including some quite popular negative viewpoints/outlooks. But I suspect that they generally do not feel a sense of powerless doom encroaching on every step, stretching interminably into the future, the way extreme nihilists often espouse.) (3/2 lol)

I'd say less 'evil' than it no longer respects the social contract with the community, and its goals don't reflect what our desires are - and will happily strip community resources to the bone for the meagrest chance that other products can benefit.

Private companies cannot be directly defined in terms of good and evil. Does the company actively seek to help those less fortunate? No. Does the company actively try to do anyone harm? No. Private companies are defined in terms of profit. There is pressure from the owners to yield profit and you do need to at least break even to stay afloat - no way around it. Therefore profit is the most fundamental, primary goal of any private company. Whereas the most fundamental and primary goals of human morality might be things like consider other people, do not cause harm etc. ->

Since a private company does not have human morality as its primary goal, it is therefore easily labelled "evil" by humans, who put morality first. The same way as we label a psychopath evil due to their lack of empathy. In fact emphathy is held forth as one of the most important human traits across pretty much all cultures and religions. And so if we expect empathy from a private company as we would from a decent human being, we will soon find out that empathy from a company is secondary at best. ->

Whereas the will to make profit is often connected to greed in human morality, which most cultures and religions regards as a vice or sin. Such is the nature of things and nothing we say or do here in some discussion post will change that.

I've recently been thinking a lot about long-term preservation of accessibility of  information.
Lately, I got university access to a whole lot of information, such as research papers, which really helped drive home how frustating it is to have that knowledge and information locked behind a paywall or simply gone.
Luckily, freely sharing and storing information is really one of the primary goals of the Stack Exchange network as a whole. People ask questions, other people answer, and that knowledge is now available for the public. Other people edit and improve the content, creating a repository of knowledge that is freely accessible to all.
Unfortunately, having a centralized, free, repository of knowledge available doesn't necessarily ensure that it will stay that way.
The Internet Archive recently went down due to malicious actors, highlighting the issues with relying on a single source for long-term preservation - or even two sources. The Internet Archive is the primary tool that most people rely on to back up information here on SE, from preserving the SE webpages themselves to the off-site resources linked-to by them. Assuming a worst-case scenario, if both Stack Exchange and the Internet Archive are compromised, get taken down, or decide to paywall their content,1 then we are left without free access to all of that information that we've built up over the last fifteen years.
We do have the data dumps. However, the process for accessing Stack Exchange data dumps was recently changed, which has made obtaining and preserving a backup of the entire network much more difficult. (There are community-developed tools to get a network-wide dump, but it now requires being able to run such a script, dodging the SE rate limits, and creating a profile on each site - a relatively significant amount of effort.)
Before it was changed, the data dump lived at the Internet Archive, which meant that it didn't rely on SE itself, but it was (is?) then vulnerable to the same problems as everything else on the Internet Archive. The data dump even currently also doesn't back up images, which are often integral to understanding the post, and the alt text is, unfortunately, usually insufficient to replace the image in long-term data preservation.
The data dump also only addresses half the problem. Long-term storage of the content has other issues; link rot and decaying images can remove supporting evidence or references, and information becomes less relevant and goes out of date as advancements in various fields are made.
So while the data dump is a good step in the right direction when it comes to preserving the knowledge on the network, it doesn't entirely solve our issues. There's no real way to guarantee that the backup will remain free and accessible without to a degree abusing the current data dump system, dedicating gigabytes of personal storage space to storing it, and then somehow allowing external access to it. We also need to better make sure that the information is transformed into a format where it can be preserved long-term, such as lessening the reliance on images, improving the alt text process, and making it clearer when information is likely to eventually go out of date.
To sum up: our current system in theory caters towards creating a long-term repository of information, but a lot of the content on the network simply isn't designed for long-term preservation, and we don't have any good methods of ensuring that the knowledge is preserved in the long run.

1 Incidentally, one of the reasons for creating the data dump in the first place, in case the company abandoned the goal of freely accessible information.

Thank you for writing this. There's a part of me that almost wants to say that SE was never set up with this kind of archival and preservation quality in mind. Fundamentally, we are a pile of questions with a bunch of answers attached to them: the perfect haystack. And we know two facts from archival studies: first, that preservation takes active labor, and is not something you can count on to happen passively; second, that the labor required to preserve everything is insurmountable, and prioritization decisions must be made.

We lean heavily on search engines to help users find needles in that haystack. This works if what users are looking for is "fresh," recent enough to be relevant. But if the answers weren't properly preserved and maintained then the average answer is less useful to them with time. The data dump is nice, maybe as a sort of backstop, but this problem isn't solved by the data dump whatsoever, except insofar as it helps preserve unpreserved content.

Just to add, I've been working with staff/trying to get a full copy of the data dump for... well from when the current system was internally announced. More critically, I'm trying to get a process in place for it - Even where folks are willing to put in the work, and resources, there's a lot of effort both in terms of the company, and community involved.

@Slate "SE was never set up with this kind of archival and preservation quality in mind" Does this mean that you think it never had the goal to do this or it never had the actual means to do this? Because it we are speaking about the goal, I am pretty sure Jeff would have something to say about how THEY intended the datadump to help with this issue and how the new management borderline sees the public availability of data a menace. If you instead means that the solution was always half baked I can agree but...  well, I'll take a half baked archive over having to jump thru fire rings every day.

@ꓢPArcheon The latter, not the former. The engine is a system for collecting Q&A pairs; it does not currently have (for example) a mechanism to systematically maintain Q&A pairs that are particularly important, or to ensure that the most important Q&A pairs are the most discoverable to users (outside of search engine indexing, which we do not directly control). It does have some basic curation tools that indicate when a question is not a good fit, but this is quite a fragmentary solution to the problem.

Preservation of knowledge cannot be left in the hands of private companies, simple as that. It is a quite unprofitable business. As for open-source volunteers, they tend to be unreliable over time, whereas preservation of knowledge requires the opposite: consistent and reliable handling over time. So what we end up with is the realization that it has to be handled by governments. Preferably democratic governments who don't weigh knowledge in terms of good and bad.

I haven’t been around nearly as long as most, but I still have my opinions on the company.
I think the company cares about numbers far too much.
They care about the amount of users in total. The amount joining per day. The amount of questions and answers a day. They care about how many people visit their sites.
But do they care about the 1% of people who actually allow the company to function and thrive?
The consistent users, who answer and edit every day. The moderators, who moderate. Even the people who just upvote and downvote every day.
Do they care about how many spammers mods destroy? How many questions I edit and close every day?
I think less. They care less than they should.

Because guess what, StackExchange? If you lose that 1%, you basically lose your business model.
Give mods more tools, give the community more of a say, give the 1% credit for what they do.

I love the network and it’s respective communities.
But I shouldn’t have to love it less because SE has the wrong priorities.

I think the company should care about numbers. numbers can represent the platform succeeding in its mission. finding the right numbers to look at and thinking of what to do to sustain and grow them is something I hope the company does. does the company share the same core mission and direction of approach as the original founders and the community? that's the hard hitting question.

@starball I agree. Which is why I said I think they care about the key community less; too little. I never said they should forget about the business side of things. I think it needs to more balanced, however, which was basically the whole point of my answer.

It's a company. They have to break even at minimum and they can't rely on good faith for that. If you can predict profits, then you have a healthy business going. For example the number of ad views over time - that's something concrete you can measure and calculate. The amount of users lost over time because the site is filled with spam... it's a loss of profit sure, but way harder to predict or calculate.

Hello @Slate. I am sorry to bother you, as I am sure you are very busy. Firstly, I want to say what others have already: thank you for asking this question; it has been a valuable way for the community to share their opinions. But I am also wondering what you think of my answer, seeing as the community seems to have taken it fairly well. I would greatly appreciate your feedback, criticism, or both, if you have any. Cheers

@security_paranoid Going to be OOO for a bit - did read, have thoughts, but will be a bit before I reply!

What motivates you to continue editing and closing questions when the company does not care?

@CriticizeSEactionsmeansban maybe you have misunderstood my message. I am not giving up on SE, and I edit and close etc. to support the community and help others. I don’t have a problem with the community (in fact, the opposite,) I have a minor problem with the company. Not the lovely staff themselves, the execs. From your aptly named username I take it you disagree with my answer?

I fear that the need for stackoverflow.com as it currently is structured has more or less passed.
It's not necessarily that people don't need answers anymore, or that people aren't willing to answer, but as a whole I don't feel it really serves the needs that real developers have today. It's great as a resource to find solutions to already solved problems, but... you can only find them using 3rd party tools and those tools now provide our solutions without introducing users to Stack Overflow, meaning we've lost the primary source of new users and without new users we aren't getting new answerers or askers. Pair that with asking questions on SO being such a daunting and difficult process and it's easy to assume why people aren't participating. I believe it is far too late to do anything meaningful against this problem given all of the historical data has already been consumed by these 3rd parties. No amount of blocking or partnering with them will reverse this. The best we can do is make asking less of a process and more likely to result in a positive outcome for those that do decide to participate.
When I joined the network, my purpose for participating was primarily helping other users with a secondary goal of exposing myself to as many problems as possible to grow my own ability as a developer. I don't feel like either of these two purposes really exist here anymore. The former maybe, but that would require motivated askers (with non answered questions) who turn into answerers... and without a reoccurring influx of new users every year things are only going to diminish.

"without a reoccurring influx of new users" - Maybe SE's Q/A model has finally found its limit. Nowadays the "average user" doesn't want to search through a well stablished knowledge base. Instead, they prefer to ask the same question again and again, either here or to an AI (even if the former can give better solutions, they still choose the latter). I believe it's an irreversible trend, and there's not much more to do. Maybe SE should close the sites to new content (as most of the new posts are crap) and leave them in read-only mode (as most pageviews are from non-logged users anyway).

For what it's worth, @hkotsubo, if true, it's not a new phenomenon. People have been struggling with that since the days of IRC. "RTFM" first appeared around 40 years ago. The desire to ask one's question in a personal way and receive an answer from another person is timeless, and a perennial problem for spaces that claim to offer those answers. (I'd guess that it partially explains some friction users have with duplicate closures: whether or not the closure is right, it feels like a system redirecting them instead of a person responding to them.)

I generally agree that dupe handling is necessary, but I fear that by only allowing novel or new questions severely hampers the community’s ability to grow. By having such a tight hold on new answerers to the point where they often receive comments lamenting that they answered a dupe, it chokes out newer answerers from being able to grow and improve in the same way I did when I was new here. I don’t know what the solution is (or that it’s even a problem), this is just my observation.

@hkotsubo I think you'd find "people these days..." just echoes the same concerns as in the olden days. The network has been struggling with duplicate questions since its inception. Because it's the same thing as before SE existed. It was created partly in response to incessant repeat questions over and over. So there would finally be a place on the internet you can find the question before you asked it. Trying to blame "modern users" for this trend shows blindness for why SO exists at all.

@Slate and VLAZ: Sorry for the misunderstanding, let me try to rephrase it. I didn't mean that only new users are responsible for that. My point is that currently, most users behave this way (regardless of when they started participating). The prefer-to-ask-again behaviour must be an old thing, but my perception is that in the past they weren't the majority in SE sites (or at least the problem was more manageable), and now they are, to the point of making the Q/A model unfeasible.

People ask again because they haven't found an answer, if they had an answer they wouldn't be asking. unfortunately it's a nearly impossible thing to fix, because you can't just make people good at finding answers or understanding what exactly it is they even need to ask. the Stack Overflow solution to it with dupe closure was a revolutionary solution, 15 years ago, and still mostly works.

@hkotsubo the general explanation of the plateau we saw in 2014 was that SO reached it's limit... that user attrition finally caught up with user growth, that SO had somehow reached it's limit in terms of how long it could keep an engaged user compared to yearly user growth. That it was more or less doomed to, each year, lose a larger number of engaged users. but... I'd argue what we're actually seeing is less and less new users. Less new users who find reason to pick up the torch. Less new users who even bother to click through the quick answer to SO to see the source.

In a sense, mission accomplished, for better or worse, in a world where SO is no longer that new and shiny place everyone wants to be a part of and is instead that place search engines and LLM's get their source data from until it's too old to be relevant.

@Slate "it feels like a system redirecting them instead of a person responding to them" - I've seen people complaining about that and saying that AI is better because "it's polite and doesn't close my question", even if the AI answer is worse or simply wrong. Which makes me think that people don't really want the best, more accurate answers. If you're "polite" enough, they'll accept anything that "works". SE has the power to change this mindset. Instead, they're embracing the AI hype, and quality (and also attribution) no longer seems to be a priority.

I think that's probably somewhat true, @hkotsubo. I'd be inclined to hypothesize that many people, in practice, don't actually care for what's true in the "thorough, vetted, attributed" sense, but rather what's true enough in the "I can make something with this" sense. If an LLM is wrong, some people probably believe it will either be so wrong as to be obviously useless or not wrong enough to worry about. As a knowledge service we are, of course, most interested in the "thorough, vetted, attributed" sense. Maybe there is a diverging need there - but then, I'm just speculating.

The value proposition is (was?) in the people who contribute expertise
Unless you - SO/SE - recapture that core value, your niche will keep shrinking.   And this breaks my heart. SE/SO has been in many ways a good experience.
I was asked a few years ago on Aviation SE to run for moderator, since I did a lot of moderation queue work on that stack, but I declined.  I have spend multiple decades in aviation, first in flying, now in repair, so I've got something to offer.  There were numerous reasons for that refusal - I moderate a professional forum, and those are also feeling the pinch - but the bottom line was that what SO corporate had done to mutate * cough * change the site ended up degrading the humans who had built it.
It wasn't just the Monica case - a symptom of a larger problem - but the general and overall devaluation of the human element.
SO/SE has made some errors on the community manager side
We've lost talent, and goodwill, based on how the company has treated their community managers.  The community managers (who have to herd cats on the diamond mods, writ large, and for the community of volunteers in general) were a critical piece of the value proposition in that they could help the enterprise wield the power of volunteers.
That is a thing that made SO/SE unique; people giving of themselves for the greater good combined with good signal to noise ratios.  I have learned in a few church, and other charitable / non-profit, groups how important it is to treat your volunteers well.
When you don't they ghost you.
Why? A rough sentiment comes across something like this:
I'm not taking this kind of abuse for free, I put up with it at work where they pay me. Good bye.
And sometimes they just stop showing up without telling you anything.
Is it possible to restore the trust relationship necessary for a site whose engine room is constructed from a body of volunteers, when time and again the knife has gone into the back?
I don't know.  Corporate leadership comes off as tone deaf.
Where I'd once have offered a little of my expertise (in dealing with people and with volunteers) on a path forward for this enterprise for free, once bitten twice shy.  The juice isn't worth the squeeze.
Bottom line: it's about the people
Unless SO/SE makes adjustments with that principle foremost, the entropy (enshittification as noted in another post) will be inexorable.
On the bright side, I donated a nice piece of swag (an SE T-shirt I got for something a few years back) to the local homeless shelter, and I got a grin out of seeing someone wearing it as I was working the food line last month.
Someone mentioned their disappointment that SO/SE didn't go non profit. Maybe that would have been a better path forward, but it was the path not taken. (Thank you, Robert Frost).
In closing, I will badly paraphrase a political meme from 1992, a simple message isn't getting through to corporate leadership: it's the people, st___d.

I feel like the company is slowly driving away community members one by one.
I know a lot of this has definitely been said before, but I'm worried about the trust issues between the company and us - the community - getting so bad that everyone decides to just up and leave. Actually, some people are already doing that. I'm worried that people genuinely devoted to the site, who spend actual effort investing in everything from clearing the review queues to talking in chat, will just leave, and have their spots replaced by people who just answer for the reputation points.
I'm worried because I don't want to lose the connection with a lot of genuinely great people I've met here on Stack Exchange. I've seen a conversation about the future - it was mentioned that eventually SE might devalue enough to the point where we can just buy it. I feel like that might actually have a chance of happening. Another thing said was that the eventual death of the site is basically inevitable unless it branches out into something new.
My mental image in maybe a decade is that Stack Overflow will remain on the internet, devoid of anyone willing to pay attention or moderate. The amazing, helpful questions and answers will remain, but in a graveyard that slowly fills up with spam. I'm trying to be optimistic. And this makes me sad because my entire generation, including most of the programmers I know, grew up with Stack Overflow. Got a problem? Stack Overflow it. Obscure bug? Look on Stack Overflow. Another thing might just be that almost all the easy questions are already answered - it's hard to ask a good new question that hasn't been answered.
A lot of people might just be willing to scrape chat for all the nostalgic moments and memories and then up and leave the site. I haven't reached that point yet, but I'm not sure I'm still that far away.

You listed three major roles on this network in your question:

Consumers of the knowledge stored here, those who create and store knowledge, and the people who operate the place itself (not limited to employees), who all together produce the thing we call “Stack Exchange.”

My biggest worry is that those three roles don't agree on what Stack Exchange should be.
First - those who "create and store knowledge" - which I interpret as "the people who answer, edit, vote on, close, migrate, review, and flag posts" on a regular basis. Overwhelmingly, this group seems to be guided by the mission statement in the tour: "We build libraries of high-quality questions and answers, focused on each community's area of expertise." We care about the longevity of the information stored here - which can mean making good things, improving bad things, or filtering out the unrecoverable.
Second - the "consumers of the knowledge." I could see this as meaning "the people who find answers here here via Google," but that group generally won't be very engaged with this platform - I care much more about the people who ask new questions on SE sites. People ask questions for different reasons, but everyone who asks a question wants an answer - and in many cases, they want it soon.
And finally - "the people who operate the place itself." I'm going to focus primarily on the company here even though that's not the only group in question. I believe that many of the company's goals align with the other two groups' - particularly the first's - but as a for-profit company, Stack Exchange, Inc also has to care about making money. If the product stops being profitable, the company fails - so although content quality and UX matter, they kind of have to be second to making the numbers go up.
I've only been here for a couple months, but I can already tell that these groups' goals are diverging - and I worry that our communication isn't working well enough to prevent that.
An easy example is the plethora of "why was my question closed?" Q&As on Meta. Each one represents a divergence of goals: the asker wants their problem solved, and the community doesn't think answering unfocused or off-topic questions will help create that lasting library of information. But it also represents a failure of communication - because without things like proper onboarding, there's no way for a new user to guess that the community will react so badly. And that, in turn, gets back to the divergence in goals itself - because proper onboarding requires company intervention, and if onboarding isn't really profitable, how feasible is it for the team to spend time improving it?
I see Stack Overflow's Discussions as another failure of communication. Not in quantity of communication - there was plenty of community feedback, particularly as the spam started ramping up - but in its response. Many members of the community spoke up about the spam problem, but it took a long time for that communication to produce meaningful change. And like with onboarding, some of that can be traced back to divergence in goals - to a community member, a page chock-full of spam is anathema to the site's core objectives, but to Stack Exchange, fixing it just might not have enough of an ROI to make it worth the dev time.
And, of course, there's the gen AI fiasco. To me, this is the clearest case of both goal divergence and communication failure. To a new user, gen AI might seem great - it makes it way easier to ask and answer questions, sometimes churning out a 30+ minute post in seconds. But to a longtime community member, that same gen AI tool threatens to inject credible-sounding garbage into the library they've worked so hard to maintain. And to the company, AI may be receiving negative reactions from core users, but it's also the biggest, flashiest technology of the last few years - and capitalizing on it now might be the best chance to attract funding for a long time in the future. Communication challenges magnify all that - new users often aren't informed of gen AI policies when they first join, for example, and we've seen community-company dialogue fail time and time again.
None of this is to meant to draw attention to any particular issue or to over-emphasize the Most Recent Calamities. Rather, I want to highlight the structural tensions that I've noticed since I first opened Meta. So if you're asking me what I'm worried about? I worry that in the long term, these goals will continue to diverge without communication to bring them back together - that new users will see the community as hostile, that the community will see new users as lazy, that distrust of the company will continue to pile up, and that many of the company's actions will continue to deserve that distrust. This site can't survive without the people who asks questions, the volunteers who answer and organize them, or the company that keeps the servers running, and it definitely can't survive if our shared goals and obligations get lost in translation.
But I also have hope that good-faith communication will continue, that there are people who remember those shared goals, and that people on all sides will keep trying to keep the network alive. I don't think that faith is misplaced, either. Onboarding may not be perfect, but experiments like SO's Staging Ground are a step in the right direction. Discussions improvements may have taken a while, but they're starting, and even small changes have markedly reduced the amount of spam. And I know that people in the company care, Slate, because you took the time to write up this question and engage with the answers. So thanks for keeping this site alive a little longer - because if distrust and divergence are what's going to kill it, genuine, open, and honest communication like this are what's going to keep it alive.

"but I can already tell that these groups' goals are diverging" no, I don't think this is a new or worsening problem / perceived problem. exhibit n: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252077/11107541. in fact, with the launch of staging ground, if anything, things are systematically aligning toward quality as a prioritized standard.

"..these goals will continue to diverge without communication to bring them back together" Just a small comment: The goals of the different participating groups will never completely align. A compromise of some sort will always be needed. The question is probably, which compromise best fits every group and what best means there. Best may be  something like sustainability, that the service is still relevant and used in the future. So far there doesn't seem a clear unanimous path towards it.

@starball I agree, this isn’t a new problem. But it’s a very obvious one, to the point where you notice it really fast if you spend any amount of time on meta.

Anerdw - thanks for answering! This is quite a good point and very worth being called out (even if it isn't exactly "new"). It speaks to the core questions of "what do we care about", "what do we believe in", and "what do we want to build". The communication challenges exist, and the diverging desires exist. Still, those can be made easier with a shared sense of purpose, with an agreed-upon mission (if you will) that we can get behind on and use as the lens through which we judge pursuits: does it foster the mission? It's an interesting ask.

@CesarM That "foster the mission" perspective is also why I'm willing to be a little lenient about the recent AI stuff that's been going on. I dislike AI as much as the next person, but at the same time...Stack Exchange needs to keep the lights on. And if creating a Copilot extension or alpha-testing the Answer Bot is the price we pay to keep the site up, that's a tradeoff I'm honestly willing to pay.

First of all, thanks for asking. Unlike previous attempts this one appears genuine  and coming from the heart.
Took me whole night (well, the hours before sleep) to figure out what Stack Overflow was, how it was supposed to be when created, etc. And just now I noticed balpha already nailed it, and in an excellent way. I really couldn’t say it better and this saves me from writing couple of paragraphs.
Also, same as balpha, I write “Stack Overflow” as that is the flagship and engine, but of course I refer to the whole network and/or the company.
Now that the background is set, let’s jump to the future, aka what comes to my mind when I think about the future of Stack Overflow. Sadly, the TL;DR here is not good. I see no future for Stack Overflow in its current form. Unless it would go through a really drastic change, 10 years from now it would not exist anymore as public Q&A site. (the paid version would stay.)
That’s something balpha also mentioned in his answer, but naturally I have to elaborate and refer to the other questions of what troubles me and what gives me hope.
Note: all the below is my own personal opinion, based on what I see and hear. I don’t have data to back it up, and in some cases I really hope to be wrong and see things as worse than they really are. But the discussion here does call for honest opinions, so that is what I give.

Why wouldn’t Stack Overflow survive? Because critical mass of core users are going to leave and/or stop curating. This will cause the site to be flooded with low quality posts that would not get edited, off topic questions not closed or deleted, and it would become impossible to find decent answers. After a while, views would decrease, new questions won’t be asked, and new answers would add little to no value. By all means, that is considered a death for a Q&A site.
And don’t get it wrong: this mass Exodus has already began. Still not critical mass, and that’s what gives me hope it can still be handled and perhaps even reversed.
Why the core users leave? Because they are unhappy with the direction the company choose to follow. Because their actual concerns are neglected at best, or plainly ignored at worst. Because the company is trying to cover the real direction with noise and bells, instead of being straight forward and address painful conflicts.
This is, in big part, because of the huge elephant in the room, that balpha mentioned as well.
Shiny and golden, sparkling with potential and promise, the elephant persuaded Stack Overflow to ride it, to put their future in it. That by itself might not be bad and possibly the only way to survive in the short run, however that is not the point at all. The point is that it was done without proper communication with the above core users, except for some very poor attempts, that (again, in my opinion) were never real. The course was set, is still being set, regardless what the actual users think. And that worries me and troubles me.
However, the GenAI hype is going to subside, like a bubble it can’t possibly keep growing forever.
The company will have to change direction again, find a different course to sail. But by then, it will be too late.
So, how can such a future be avoided, and instead have a thriving site and community in 2035? Drastic changes are required, no doubt.
The company needs someone who is both involved deep in the “new generation” of programmers, as well as having the “spirit” of the first days of Stack Overflow. Kind of “these days” Jeff Atwood, who can think out of the box.
Another way is to harness the power of this very community, and start a separate, official, discussion calling people to give their suggestions how Stack Exchange should change in 10 years, including any drastic measures they can think of.
But no matter what changes will be done, it can’t work without complete collaboration with the community members. Each step must be discussed, and feedback not only collected, but actually have impact. That is the thing that is missed the most.

Thanks for reading, and I will sum things up with some extra. I do not think Stack Exchange is evil, I believe the company lost its original way when it was sold to Prosus, and Joel’s original promise has been broken. My trust in management is broken beyond repair, however I still see others who have some trust, and what keeps me around are the friends I acquired over the years, and the still existing desire to make things a bit better.
The middle layer of the company aka the Community Management team also consists of people whom I trust, hence I am posting this answer, knowing someone from that team will read it, but I’m beyond hope it will actually have any impact. (For example, management changing their ways or setting a different direction.)

Hey, first I want to say - thanks for writing. You're often one of the folks I see choose not to give feedback, because "what's the point?" - and I don't mean that as criticism. Seeing you take the time to respond at all gives me an unexpected amount of hope that the problems we're facing today might be tractable to address jointly. You might not share that hope - I know you say that at least some part of trust is probably irreparable for you. But regardless, I have to thank you for it, and for taking the time.

"Another way is to harness the power of this very community, and start a separate, official, discussion calling people to give their suggestions how Stack Exchange should change in 10 years, including any drastic measures they can think of." - very interesting. This is not as off-the-wall as it might seem, and it is an idea worth taking seriously.

There's a strong argument that it would lead to a saner future than finding a "Jeff Atwood replacement," too. Institutions organized around organic, emergent, shared values (a "mission" [buzzword alert]) are often sturdy and strong. Institutions organized around a person's dream can be efficient and compelling, but are often brittle under disruption/disagreement, and can quickly lose their sense of order and purpose. The most effective values are usually ones many people feel personally and carry with them. I wonder what our model of the future would look like if built around this idea...

@Slate thanks for the replies, and while having that "10 years brainstorming" would be really nice, I really doubt it will have any actual impact - though I will most likely take part in that as well, impact or not. As for building around a mission and not around a person you're correct, but I think Jeff did have the mission in front of him, the mission was his dream, and that's how he was so successful. But I don't think there's anyone else who can do it these days, hence my suggestion. Anyway enjoy your time off, I'll wait patiently. :)

In a sense though - the past few years have been brittle and disruptive cause there's no cohesive vision. There isn't been any real order, nor purpose but profit, and a willingness to break down pillars of our network to chase that.  We've tried not having "a Jeff" - or the people covering what we did. Both in terms of social software - (ponder slashdot post acquisition), and tech companies in general (consider Dell and Apple), Charismatic leadership and trust... work. Even if we don't have a Jeff, Keeping our Catjas, Nicks, Shogs and Tims would be helpful.

The company kind of hasn't valued those sort of ICs, and actively seems to shed, and not recruit the sort of people who have those effective communication skills.

Thanks for posting this! It's great to have a venue for ... just discussion, without any promises that it will lead to action, but to share thoughts and ideas.
Disclaimer: I haven't read all of the other answers posted here so far, so apologies in advance if I'm repeating some points that were already made by others.

Thinking towards the long-term future of the network, I guess my main concern is: is SE still relevant, and for how long can it remain so? This breaks down into a number of facets of the broader issue, sub-concerns and reasons to be worried or to have hope.

The world simply moves on. When something becomes no longer relevant or interesting/useful to a large number of people, that doesn't mean there's anything wrong with it. We just live in a very fast-changing world, especially now in the internet era. I don't like it (hell, I work in one of the few areas where knowledge is pretty much fixed forever and things from 2000 years ago are still valid and useful), but it's a fact. How long can one website, or network of websites, actually remain relevant - no matter how good it is?

AI is essentially a competitor to Q&A sites. Put yourself in the shoes of someone who has a question and wants an answer to it. They can ask ChatGPT or some equivalent AI bot, or they can ask some expert humans on a site like SE. The former is much faster - nothing can be done about that - but the latter has the advantage of greater reliability, at least in theory. Still, a lot of people don't know or don't care about the disadvantages of genAI, and will be happy to accept an answer from ChatGPT in almost all cases. It makes sense, then, that the number of people posting questions on SE has declined in recent years.
What can be done about it? I've seen this said before (don't remember where, sorry I can't cite the source), but SE can and should use its advantages over genAI as a selling point. That's one of the reasons why genAI answers on SE are such a bad thing - people can get genAI answers without needing SE, and one of the great things about SE is how it involves real expert people who can give answers that can't be found anywhere else (and therefore couldn't be given by genAI which is trained only on existing knowledge). You've got that advantage over genAI answering services, so use it! You won't bring back the people who've left SE to ask ChatGPT instead, but at least you'll keep the people who value SE for what it is, and attract new people who've realised how unreliable tools like ChatGPT can be.

Lots of the network sites are already dying. Only a few have actually been shut down (Productivity, Startups, Windows Phone), but others have had multiple failed mod elections and probably (you'd know better) face a serious risk of shutting down, and many others are essentially dead sites even if you have managed to find three people willing to mod them (often multi-site mods who don't mind adding another little site to their list). Even the large and still-busy sites feel less active in terms of community than they were some years ago, with a few people still churning out answers but not as much community-building activity as there used to be. I feel like I can literally see the network dwindling.
This points to SE becoming less relevant, at least in certain domains of knowledge. If a site used to be more active and now has almost no new posts, that means it used to have value for a bunch of people interested in a certain topic, who have now presumably moved on elsewhere to share their knowledge.
What can be done about it? Maybe not much: after all, you can't force people to come and participate on any site. But maybe SE could do more to promote itself - to advertise its Q&A services, not just in the tech industry but also various non-technical communities for whom some of the network sites could be really useful. Maths Overflow is extremely successful, attracting really world-leading mathematicians to participate, and I think that's because it has a good reputation within the specialist community, so mathematicians in universities across the world know that they can use it to get good answers to serious questions. If that reputation could be cultivated in other specialist communities, other SE sites might become equally successful and valuable.
Alternatively, if the company could arrange or at least explicitly encourage some community-building activities, that could go a long way towards rebuilding communities that have dwindled. Obviously not on every site, but if you just did it on a very few sites, the word might spread across the network and communities could get inspired to organise their own events on other sites. (From my own experience, sometimes it only takes one or two people to re-ignite a chatroom into a buzzing hive as the activity snowballs larger, and sometimes a fun community event on one site will inspire similar events on other sites if some users are active on both.)


What gives me hope? Well, certainly some sites on the network are still relevant and have a strong reputation within their subject area. I hope the knowledge collected on those sites will always remain visible to all, no matter what decisions the company makes in the future. Some sites, too, still have strong communities and a positive vibe that gets stuff done.
I do think there's a bunch of inactive sites on the network that should be shut down - perhaps made read-only, to preserve the content without need for moderation, or their content migrated to some other sites if possible. That might give CMs more time to do more for the healthy sites, without needing to spend their time doing things like arranging multiple back-to-back failed elections.
Finally, even if SE does become irrelevant or crash and burn, I'll take solace in the fact that my time spent here hasn't been wasted. This is more personal than "hope for the network", but I've learned a huge amount from my participation on SE, both in terms of transferrable skills (like persuasive writing and people skills) and in terms of knowledge in various topics (especially literature).

Sorry for the late post, but you did say you'd read all the answers no matter how late they were posted. I kept a draft open in a tab for a long time, and I do feel like this answer kind of peters out towards the end, as maybe I didn't plan/structure it very well. Hopefully it's still useful as food for thought!

I agree with the suggestion of trying to sell the advantage of humans over genAI. My employer sent a communication which said any output from genAI is only to be used after getting a human to verify the information is correct. Which means you might as well bypass genAI and just ask a human.

@ChesterGillon And conversely, if SE starts offering AI-generated answers, then you might as well bypass SE and just ask an AI.

"SE can and should use its advantages over genAI as a selling point" that's what I see them doing at least in writing in their blog posts. the whole "trust" thing. "But maybe SE could do more to promote itself" I'd also like to see the company promote the network sites more.

The company has no attention span.
We have core components of the network that were worked on - like the new editor, that seems to have been suddenly abandoned. There's other examples of this.
SE's focus has jumped from public Q&A to careers 1.0, to Teams, to now trying to shoehorn AI somewhere. In between, we had things like Documentation which was an attempt to move beyond Q&A. But Q&A is still the core of what SE's about and what it's good at.
We've also had very positive steps to better the network and relationships that suddenly got dropped cause something else is more important to the management.
Apologies to people with ADD but the company has corporate ADD, and once a good, solid Q&A system was 'complete', has been floundering about the 'next thing' to the detriment of 'what it was good at'.

I don't think this is caused by a lack of focus, more by an excess of focus on "profit", that in turn switches around the goal whenever the monetization plan changes. Currently, AI just happens by sheer chance to be the current "big seller" bubble that someone expect to make big $$$ of, and Google is playing the role of the lamb to what is seen as an easy-con job, but that could change if a new smoke and mirror tech emerges. I don't expect the company to really believe the AI buzztalk, I just expect the company to be "acting out" the AI evangelist role for "Ezy muney"

@ꓢPArcheon I think JG is suggesting the same thing; focusing too much on trends and hype trains to maximize profit, instead of building viable products and waiting for them to reach fruition. They just decided to depict it as corporate ADD, but the message is not lost, at least not for me.

Hey, it's starball speaking. Slate, I'm very happy you're starting this discussion and listening.
I feel like I need to preface my thoughts with a bit about who I am, just so it's established to the reader where I'm coming from, since no matter how hard/little I try/pretend to think on behalf other people on this platform, what I want for the future will be polarized to my own experiences and values.
So- about me. I'm a lover of music who somehow found myself studying computers. Among other resources like documentation, youtube videos, and blog posts, I benefitted from Stack Overflow significantly in my studies and continue to do so. When I first entered my program of study, the first time I went on Stack Overflow and created an account, I remember thinking I'd be crazy and depraved to get sucked into this gamified system. After I graduated, I did... Cheers to being crazy and depraved, I guess .
There was a period of ~2 years where I was heavily involved in answering questions about VS Code and CMake. I climbed the rep ladder and enjoyed it (too much for my own good). I participated in a few burninations, hung out in the SOCVR chatroom for a while, made bug reports and feature requests, sent a few charcoal reports, and took part in beta tests. I earned a dup hammer and tried to make good use of it, often going doing rabbit trails in web searches to point people to canonicals. I drive a humble, steady stream of traffic here- several pages of link-sharing-badges-worth. I was a hair-width away from being elected as a moderator on Stack Overflow earlier this year, which I'm quite proud of.
These days, due to being busier (and that's a good thing), I've reduced my participation to deleting unnecessary comments and non-answer posts, and sometimes downvoting content in my main tag that I don't consider useful. Sometimes I review in Staging Ground. I am still somewhat involved on MSO and MSE, though less than I was a few months ago.
All that is to say- I have spent a fair amount of time and mental energy into trying to learn the ways of this communal library of information, and to make it a cleaner, more useful place. Playing the game made me care about it. Caring about it made me invest in it. Investing in it just made me care more about it (positive reinforcement(?)).


Who are we?

We are problem-solvers and makers. Curious people and experts. Readers, authors, and volunteer librarians and janitors.
The regulars are just total weirdoes. *avoids eye contact with my reflection on my screen*. I half joke, but that's genuinely what I think too. The deepest layers of this place seem to attract a certain genre of oddballs.
In our (speaking of the contributors as a whole now) idealized form, I see us as something like the study group (think private group chats or walled gardens like Discord), the office hours (think maintainer-operated forums like Discourse), and the helpful colleague (think LLM) but designed for time and energy efficiency at massive scale.

Where do we want to be?

Our idealized form, I hope. Or as close to it as we can get.
(My following responses to this and the following question will be a bit self-centered)
As for myself, I don't have the time to be an "author" anymore. I just want to be empowered by the community library's sponsors as a librarian and janitor to clean up garbage and organize the stuff around me. I want a library where volunteer librarians can flourish, because I have come to want this library to be a place people love: An unmaintained community library will grow into a dysfunctional mess. Readers don't go to dysfunctional libraries unless they're desperate enough to gamble a bunch of their time and mental energy. Authors won't freely give their books where readers don't go. (okay, the anology is stretching- have mercy).

what do we need to do to achieve it?

In reference to my above response,
You (the company) trusted me enough for me to build a track record as a librarian and janitor- trust me for my track record.
Recognize the value of the sum and continuation of my contributions. Make me (and others like me) feel like an asset rather than an obstacle. Maybe even a bit as a partner.
Fix my broken tools. Regularly devote some time and money to give me good tools. Don't just fix the stuff that's easy to fix. Fix the stuff that's easy to fix and which makes my everyday contributions easier and less frustrating.
Put up nice signs in prominent places that encourage visitors to have good etiquette like "lower your voice" and "no littering" (think JIT guidance and better onboarding- things I have been mentioning for years now, and other people long before me).
Stop delivering broken things and then running away to deliver the next broken thing.
Come say hi once in a while.
This is not the first time I've said words like these. Other people have said them before me too. But I'm happier to be saying them in this context than the others.
I've focused only on what I want the company to do because I'm lazy, and it's the easiest thing to do. The company holds the platform and its mechanics. The community holds the norms, and I'd say a larger share of the guidelines (though those go in hand with the platform mechanics). Thinking and talking about evaluating and changing norms and guidelines is hard, and we (the community) are still a disparate group with different opinions and personal variations of the shared vision. It also doesn't feel as important to talk about how to do better when the mind is occupied with wanting things to not (in one's own eyes) keep getting worse outside of one's control.


When you think about the future of the network - years from now - what worries you? What makes you anxious? What do you look forward to? What might make you hopeful?

Symptoms of dereliction
I am not good at long-term thinking years ahead. But looking at Stack Overflow's site analytics, the consistent downward trend in new posts and votes seems to suggest a combination of entering a semi-maintenance mode (many questions have already been asked), a steady decline in the general population's inclination to seek answers to their questions here, and a decline in the ranking favourability that SO has in web search engines (these are guesses based on empirical evidence- not on comprehensive data, because I don't have that). It's not so much these that directly worry me.
Searchability and concentration of useful content
I'm worried that the content people want to find will not turn up for them when they look for it. There are a lot of things that threaten this.

Questions that are just unlikely to be useful to other people due to lacking an appropriate amount of issue isolation, generalization, or abstraction. These pop up endlessly and dilute the more valuable content.
Bad question titles. These frustrate the user experience of going through search results.
Lots of bad questions and questions with bad titles, and the continual growth of this problem.
Poor in-site search for technological(?) reasons.
Poor web search engine search for content quality reasons like the two categories I mentioned above.

It gives me hope that the Staging Ground has graduated from beta. It shows a commitment to quality. Quality now has its own phase before release to experts for further review / answering. It weighs on me that it seems like reviewers are much more on the ball than askers. My experience there seems to reinforce my feeling that a large proportion of askers are not invested enough in their question to "put them into shape". I suspect that it has to do with misaligned expectations about what this platform is. I hope that the company can act to help with that.
Ignoring the problem of goodness/badness being in part in the eye of the beholder, I wish the stuff that I consider bad was easier to get rid of so that it would bother people less.
For the good stuff, I think it would be really interesting (where applicable) to be able to capture what search queries led a user to something that they try to upvote. As an answerer, I'd love to know how to optimize the searchability of content I write that people find useful. Or even of content I didn't write but that I often see duplicate questions of. As an expert, I have blindness to the mental model of non-experts ("curse of knowledge"). To an extent, that information is available for frequently duplicated questions through their duplicates, but I don't see anything incentivizing or encouraging people to improve searchability of canonicals given that information. I know you didn't ask for feature-requests here, but thinking about problems made me feel a little inspired.
External search and voting
I'm worried that people will stop voting.
Voting is a core piece of this platform's model. Voting is what makes the good stuff rise to the top. That's a core part of this platform's value.
It was accepted and embraced by the creators of this platform that external search was/is a driver of incoming traffic. Now with LLMs that do web searches, there's less need for searchers/consumers to come directly onsite. That means less eyes on our voting buttons.
Ideas about integrating voting into LLM response interfaces are stuck with the messiness of trying to guess that the user would vote and how, or that they don't care to spend extra time to go cast a vote onsite, or don't have the privilege to.
I recognize that I'm echoing concerns behind company initiatives that I've challenged in the past year or so (the designs- not necessarily the concerns). I just don't know what a good solution is (though I've had related ideas that I still believe in and would like to see implemented/tried). At this point, I don't know what to hope either. Maybe that if we can do something about all the content badness making searches ineffective, people will click into the site more.
I have a hunch that what we do will still be needed years later, even if just to be a source that feeds the next generation of machines (like LLMs) for the next generation of new questions. It gives me hope that I see in external discourse that significant chunks of the general population think the same way.
Divide between community and company
I started becoming heavily involved here in ~2022. When I discovered MSO and MSE, and saw how strong the company involvement with the community was in the early days, I was amazed. It was awesome. Then when I compared to how divided things are between the company and community, it shocked me. I went down rabbit holes reading about things that happened in 2019 and it was a really unhappy experience (for me just reading about it) fueled by morbid curiosity. I regularly saw lots of discontent and plenty of anger on meta and in chat. I came to accept it as the standard of living here- at least on meta. Then I got to experience it with front-row seats with all that followed the release of ChatGPT. And though there have been some resolutions like the strike negotiation results, and some wins like the announcement of Community Asks Sprints, the net trend does not look up from where I'm sitting and what I want to see. Any lift forces I see are not strong enough.
I no longer worry that that trend will continue downward. I have silently and unconsciously come to expect it to. Maybe it's just that I'm no longer fanatically involved, and am now busier with the rest of my life, but recently whenever something new pops up from the company that goes in a direction that concerns me or that I feel opposed to, the upswelling of reactive emotion inside me immediately fizzles out into a disappointed sigh.
I long to see the company champion the original mission similar to how it was in some "golden era" that I missed. I worry that the trend of the company being less and less involved in the community and involving the community less and less will continue.
It also weighs on me that the company appears from where I stand to have a thing for laying off staff who act as bridges in the divide, representing the voice of each side to the other. I worry that this will continue and we'll lose the remaining people who do that. I don't really have hope that more such people will be hired- just hope that those who remain get to keep their positions.
New blood
I'm worried that slowly we will lose the incoming stream of rare, crazy people who get deeply involved in maintaining and improving the libraries- who dilligently operate the review queues and try to do a good job- who vote up/down/close/reopen/delete/undelete.
I have a vague but strong feeling that it's unnecessarily difficult for a new person who wants to help out to discover and learn how. That worries me.
I also worry that it will become harder and harder for those who still come aboard to gain the privileges to make valuable contributions. Though in some ways, it also doesn't feel like too big of a problem.
Getting enough rep to make edits without peer review is so difficult. I'm not sure yet whether I think that's totally a bad thing. I have other ideas on how to make little improvements, but the edit queue still needs more people operating it.
I feel hope when once in a blue moon, I see a new face getting deeply involved- performing moderation, doing reviews, participating on meta, appearing in chatrooms.
I'm worried that new people will see all the shouty, angry, or just generally annoyed voices on meta and think they need to be like that to fit in. Have some grace for me when I say that that's what I thought for a while. I can very much be a people-pleaser. I think I've learned the voices of the regulars of meta and chat, come to distinguish those that I admire and want to emulate from those I just observe and sometimes carefully interact with (and those in between), gained enough confidence in myself from building up somewhat of my own reputation here, and come to feel less intensely about this platform- all that enabling me to (hopefully for the most part now) have a more neutral tone. I'm not perfect, but I think I'm going in a direction I'm happy with.
I feel hope when I see or remember the people I admire continuing to be themselves and continuing to be good librarians amidst... everything. I hope they keep going, and I hope I become more like them as long as I'm still active here.


My reflections have meandered down many inconclusive pathways, and prompted questions about the network that have no easy or simple resolution.

Well, now that makes two of us :)

"I have a vague but strong feeling that it's unnecessarily difficult for a new person who wants to help out to discover and learn how. That worries me." - this is an interesting point, particularly in light of how you crossed that threshold. It seems like crossing the threshold from "new here" to "serious contributor" is quite a labor of love for a lot of people. Lots to learn, lots of friction to push through. I'd honestly say that worries me, too. I wonder if it's a general experience, and the pipeline is simply so leaky that people just don't come out the other side too often.

"I'm worried that new people will see all the shouty, angry, or just generally annoyed voices on meta and think they need to be like that to fit in." - this is a fun problem. I say fun, because I enjoy community management, and that makes things like this fun somehow. But honestly? I tend to think it's a problem that sorts itself out, once a vision is presented that makes people hopeful or excited for the future. The natural enemy of communal angst is a reason to believe in where we're going. But it may take some purposeful work, too.

But it's for that ^ reason that I think, if there's anything that rattles me in your answer, it's this: "I no longer worry that that trend will continue downward. I have silently and unconsciously come to expect it to." And it's because I know you're far and away not alone in that. So the work of creating a reason to believe in where we're going will be hard. Dunno. Lot to chew on here.

@Slate to state the obvious: it's only hard because the company has made it hard for itself, through blatantly abusing the community's trust again and again and again. There have been many cases of things looking hopeful, with maybe the leadership now effecting positive change, only to end up being burnt. Again. And again. We're way past "fool me twice", and as you know trust is generally a non-renewable resource.

@AndrasDeak It's a fair point, but it's only useful to the extent it helps us think about and plan for the future. No matter why and how trust was lost, we still need to think about what comes next. It's context - very important context - but cannot get in the way of thinking and planning. Inform: yes. Aid: yes. Block: no.

@Slate "..the pipeline is simply so leaky that people just don't come out the other side too often." First such worries I remember are from around 2018, then under the "new user attrition" topic. I think Tim Post brought it forward then. There was a discussion about welcome-ness and friendly comments. What makes me wonder is that in the years before, say 2014, when askers flogged to SO in the hundred thousands per month, and the experience wasn't any better, why did they keep in doing it? Was it only because there was no alternative?

This is a great articulation of the problem(s). At least some of these are solvable, if the company and the community have the will and ability to make them happen.

Creating a canonical reference / library, and solving specific people's problems, are at odds. Canonical Q&A pairs are an exceptional situation, often requiring out-of-band negotiation (on meta, in chat – occasionally it's handled in comments) to establish: and then once they do, bye-bye personalised support on that topic.
These things do not need to be at odds. We can't really afford for them to be at odds. To build a useful reference, our collective awareness of problems needs to be up-to-date; and to build a library, our canonical references on each topic need to not be diluted by a dozen badly-answered "halp i dont unersand, fix teh codez plz" questions; and to be genuinely useful, we need access to the partial and iterative knowledge represented by those badly-answered "halp i dont unersand, fix teh codez plz" questions. (I swear: the number of times one of those questions, even unanswered, has contained the information I needed…)
I'm not saying the solution's tooling, but the solution is tooling. A radical proposal (aimed at the Trilogy):

All questions get an extra (required) meta tag: "help" or "reference".
"Help" questions are allowed to duplicate each other (by current standards), though the context needs to be sufficiently-different that you can't copy-paste an answer. (MCVEs / minreprexes are still expected.)
Marking questions as "reference" is an earned privilege. (New user questions will necessarily be "help" questions.)
Marking a "help" question as a duplicate is not considered closure. In fact, duplicate votes can be Accepted. (New answer type, maybe? Or else, tooling sugar, like the original duplicate system / current auto-comment system.)
Sufficiently-canonical "help" questions can be turned into "reference" questions by changing the tag.
A "reference" cloning an existing "help" is not considered a duplicate, if the "help" question could not be edited into a useful "reference" within the bounds of usual edit guidelines (e.g. not invalidating existing answers, not conflicting with the author's intent, not putting words into the author's mouth).

I've been thinking this for a while, but never had the opportunity to write it up. This solution's off the top of my head, and is by no means perfect: but it should somewhat convey my view of the problem.

I'm not sure if I fully agree with this proposal, but it's interesting food for thought, IMHO. Although it's primarily aimed at SO, it can also apply to any site that attracts homework-like questions.

I've been bouncing an idea very similar to this around in my head for months. If much of the friction is caused by curators (looking for pearls) coming into conflict with the average asker, what if we separated those concerns from each other? Turned it into a pipeline, instead of a mush? Not convinced it's the right idea yet, but it's been useful to mull over...

@Slate Yeah, I was thinking of running it as a separate site and seeing what happened, before raising the idea here… but you did ask!

This is a great idea, maybe post it as a feature request

@Starship It's a little big, and badly-thought-out, for a feature request imo. Maybe in six to eight weeks, we'll have something more polished.

I like the idea. It's a bigger step than what usually changes here (edges around voting buttons for example) and more fit for a complete spinoff but surely a very worthwhile idea. In general I would not even call it Q&A anymore. Canonical questions often aren't really questions but rather small focused textbooks excerpts.

I'm not sure that "help" vs "reference" is the right dichotomy, or the only applicable one.

@KarlKnechtel Quite likely. What would you suggest as alternatives?

Not sure, but I'd start by considering the Diataxis framework. I think it's important to make distinctions in kind, not just according to how well something would function as a canonical (which I guess is what you were mainly getting at). But anyway, good Q&A used as dupe targets won't normally look like reference documentation, because a) real reference documentation is normally already out there and b) it tends more to answer its own questions (e.g. in programming, people don't spontaneously ask "what methods does XYZ class have?").

Well - the community model is broken, and there's a deep mismatch in expectations.
We occasionally have long delays in responses to community requests and community moderator requests. The community has made specific requests in terms of the model and sometimes composition of the community team but these get ignored, and either we get promised things will get better when there's more resources (which is sometimes temporarily true), or from my perspective, we're gaslit, and told that the actions taken seem to be the right thing.
And well, the people who're most passionate about the network, and want to see it thrive are also the ones most affected by this. I'm asking myself "will this be taken in the spirit its written, or seen in the worst light possible" or told "this is how things have to work".
At the risk of repeating myself (in various different ways)

We don't seem to have enough people in the community team to deal with the workload. I've written a post about this in the moderator team (I could write one for meta if/when there's interest and I feel its the right time), but I've heard (privately) entirely contradictory information. At the very least periodically downsizing people for short term survival doesn't quite work when at least part of the issue is long term trust.

many aspects of the social contract are broken, and there's a disconnect between the desires of the 'core' of the community, and what seems expedient for management to try to meet their goals

perhaps it would be a worthy idea to have a small fully front facing subteam within the community team - dealing with short term, quick fixes and feedback the community has. I tend to get pushback for asking for the 'old' ways of community management being deeply embedded in the community, but I don't feel its something that's incompatible with the 'professional' model of community management. In a perfect world, I'd like to see both folks embedded in new communities, and working with 'key' new ones but I'd consider at least one person whose job is primarily community communication a massive win. SE's historically had people with these skillsets, and probably still does.


Consider the responses that 'active' devs and SREs get vs say, various AI related announcements.

we need investments of time, effort, inconvenience and money in rebuilding trust sustainably. If something is of benefit to the community, but isn't 'what we do now' - rather than dismissing it, it would be nice to see some of these things happen. This probably ties into the 'other' core issue I see - that of lack of focus.

People in positions of leadership are not engaged in a visible way with the community. I do realise people have different leadership styles but after all these years I'd expect folks to at least occasionally engage in the company's alleged flagship product.



"We occasionally have long delays in community" <-- did you perhaps mean "communication"? Otherwise, I don't understand what this means.

Community requests  and community moderator requests

@JourneymanGeek: I've tried to clarify that phrasing a bit; let me know what you think.

Looks good to me, even if I wish there was some more elegant way to see it

I'm bobble. If you've spent any significant amount of time on Puzzling Stack Exchange, then you recognize me. I am a very active curator there. I believe I'm the most active. Moderating on Puzzling has been my constant for four and a half years, from secondary school to grad school. I've made some public mess-ups, but I try to be better, to take criticism, to shift to changing public opinion (though I always end up on the stricter side of center), etc.
What do I do? Edit, vote, flag, review, push others to review, organize meta posts, run tag cleanups, write FAQs, comment to welcome users and/or explain rules. Day in, day out. I check the homepage at least twice a day (after waking up, before going to bed), usually more. I go through each post, editing and voting and commenting as I see fit. I go through the review queues. I try to keep abreast of major network updates that might be relevant to Puzzling.
Puzzling is a medium-sized site, standing at 3.7 questions/day as of writing. This makes it possible for me to get pretty near curating every single new post. It also means that I worry new users won't have a "chance" to start curating. I joke in my profile that I'm the "friendly neighborhood unelected moderator" - but if there's already a friendly neighborhood Spider-Man, and the neighborhood is small, who needs another Spider-Man? How do they start? How do they practice? How do they have room to stretch their powers, learn their limits, learn the community's limits?
There's an obvious answer to this worry, which is to just stop. My activity does drop occasionally, usually due to real-life vacations or similar. But... less gets done. Edits that I think would be useful, especially image descriptions/transcriptions, simply aren't made. Comments to explain rules or help users improve their questions get posted later or not at all. Most obviously, I've been the sole driving force behind every recent major tag clean-up.
I love my site. I genuinely enjoy curation. I want to see it done, and done right. But I have a nagging worry that what I'm doing is fundamentally unsustainable, because I'm too scared to let go of the reins to let others learn the ropes.

This worry is quite specific to my situation as a super-curator on a smallish site. Still, it's really and truly what's on my mind. These sites depend on a constant influx of new users, some of whom are supposed to take up the curation torch.
Puzzling is pretty different than the rest of the network, given how we're largely original puzzles, so some of the larger network issues (GenAI etc.) don't affect us as much. We're happy to chug along on our own under the radar. Anyways, Slate, that's my answer to your question.

I don't really get it. you doing curation isn't going to take away other peoples' opportunities to do curation. you're not a mod so your votes aren't binding. unless you operate 2-4 sock puppets fraudulently, you can't take away peoples' opportunities to do curation. unless you operate 24 hours per day, there will always be significant downtime where others can pick up. and if people want to learn to do it "right", and you consistently get it "right", then they can just look at how you do it. as you have pointed out, anyone can see your review actions, even without an account.

@starball some actions they definitely can pick up, like voting, since I can't close/reopen single-handed. But I also post a majority of the comments to explain rules to new users (each of whom only needs one), and I run a lot of meta stuff (linked in the post, e.g. tag cleanups) where I can and do handle basically everything. My edit activity, which is something anyone can do, still drastically overshadows everyone else.

So yeah, this post is a little narcissistic to think I can actually have such an effect, except that on certain cases (e.g. image descriptions) I have years of evidence in my favor that I consistently get there before anyone else considers bothering. I'm worried about Fastest Gun in the West'ing people out of the opportunity I had, which was seeing things wrong over and over until I took it into my own hands.

I do try to provide other people with the tools they might need - e.g. I pre-wrote comments explaining our attribution requirements, which I do see used by others.

FWIW, on some other medium sites I have observed animosity towards people with an impact like yours. Frequent complaints are about indiscriminate closure ("that guy just closes everything!"), especially if there is more than one such person ("these guys collude to close everything!"). Just having the load more spread out would create less of a community divide even with the same technical result. So even if your exact worry isn’t shared with other sites (it might be - I just never heard about it) the underlying problem of having only few „heavy hitters" is more universal than you might think.

Heh, I've actually sometimes taken the brunt of a new poster's frustration even if I didn't VTC, since I posted the explanatory comment and was thus the most visible person "against" them.

Thanks for the answer - despite being a quite unique perspective, I think it has several really interesting points to ponder about. As others have noted, sometimes these valuable contributions and efforts to keep the site in shape are even seen negatively by users joining up (sort of related to the challenges of onboarding on another answer). Most interestingly, I think, is that it highlights a likely need for knowledge transfer and practice of curation to other interested folks. It's reasonable/possible that on a site with 3-4 questions per day, a single person can do the brunt of curation.

However, this does lessen the chance/opportunity for other people to learn curation through practice. And the solution shouldn't be to tell dedicated folks to "well, just curate less then!". This aligns with some other things we've discussed in the CM team about more roles (not necessarily formal ones) than just diamond moderators, as well as ways to help people explore and learn about those roles. Could be something like a "curator training" or whatever it is where you (and other dedicated folks) could pass on the knowledge and let others learn things with guidance.

@CesarM I would be delighted to mentor others who want to try curation - be a sounding board, explain my philosophy, detail how to set up a meta campaign, etc. - but I can't know how to even start. Also no one has asked, but it's probably unclear that I'd be willing.

@bobble I think a system such as that shouldn't have to rely on someone asking or even a user having to set it up (if we want it to scale and for people to know it exists/is a possibility). It likely has to be somewhat baked into the product; it likely needs to be said to a new user interested in curation (perhaps once they do certain actions) that it exists, and so on. It's probably something worth investing in, maybe even in the efforts of decoupling privileges from reputation. But yeah, it's a great call-out that unless we create avenues for people to become curators, they might just not.

This is kind of a bus factor problem: if you're doing everything, that's great for you, but what happens if you quit one day? I think such issues have affected various sites, maybe not always a single person but a bunch of people quitting, either one by one or in a group after some controversy. It's relevant to more than just your situation, too: how do we push people to curate more? Offer bounties to active curators?

It's definitely a unique-ish problem – on smaller/lower-activity sites, a few highly-active contributors really can end up doing (what seems like) everything. Other busier sites tend to have the opposite problem: too much activity and not enough people to curate it.

I'm thinking that I still like this place. Not enough to really invest substantial amounts of energy and time (creation of knowledge is rewarding but also very exhausting) but surely enough to hang out and comment but also simply to read. What kept me here above all were the incredibly wise insights of many people, above all the original founders of the company, past members of staff and users. Reading their thoughts was a delight.
The platform is well thought out by now, the downvotes are at the core of the high quality. And the biggest cause of friction is insufficient guidance. But we can't hold hands all the time. Q&A isn't the solution to everything. There is no free lunch, not even in voluntary work. LLMs might scale better there as first response anyway but again they aren't free.
For years people rather ignored the slow demise (of Stack Overflow). Endless discussions about small changes. We are trapped in a local optimum. Not the worst but maybe not the same if we would start fresh today. That's why big organizations sometimes outlive themselves.
But then the company has no clue often enough and favor their pet projects, even if it's quite clear they won't fly right from the beginning (say collectives, discussions). If only they would listen more. 10 years ago it felt as if they listened to their user base, or at least to data/statistics. Lately... I don't know. I hardly understand the management gibberish in the blog or I have the feeling they extreme whitewash (social AI are just buzzwords) and do not always produce coherent arguments.
But it's not completely true either. We got the staging ground and the ask wizard, but maybe it's simply too little too late. One week sprint per quarter year may simply be not enough for solving all that needs to be solved.
Many knowledgeable people have left the platform already. Where are they now? How do they spend their time? The knowledge lives by the people. It's much less alive than it used to be.
In case it didn't become clear, the mission is to build a knowledge library. What else could it be? I honestly can't think of anything else. I really wonder what the company sees as its mission beyond making money, but hopefully it's not something nonsensical like community-driven AI. And the knowledge also needs to be consumed, but as long as there is a library, people will always find ways to consume it (if the system is open enough), I assume.
My insurance was always the data dumps and the content license. Money is involved so there is always an interest to prefer money making aspects. But I trusted management until some point. That trust is long gone. Making data dumps freely and easily available is the least the company can do. We know the history.
A non-profit like Codidact might be much better in that regard. If knowledge and software is both open source and freely available it's unlikely that the service will be misused; somebody else would immediately step in.
The decline of SO predates the advent of generative AI but surely it's a strong disruption in the way how we consume knowledge. It doesn't mean there is intelligence and the current hype about AI will ebb away at some point but it means that knowledge generators are deprived of credit where credit is due. Is it really fair and legal that machines use the content of every website to make a product and sell its output without financially compensating the knowledge creators in the first place? And what would be a fair compensation? This is a non-trivial question that nevertheless needs an answer. It's a wild West currently and favors the pirates over the farmers, the ones who actually grow the knowledge. That's not good. It's even a trap. We might actually destroy our foundations by allowing others to harvest knowledge that they didn't grow themselves. We might end up with a wasteland and worse off than before.
Even if I had the time and energy to invest in public knowledge creation, I might think twice in the current situation. I might instead feel that my work is unfairly used by big companies (and Stack Exchange Inc. is definitely on the side of the big companies there), which anyway have lots of money. I might kind of be on strike (knowledge generation strike) for the time being. I'm not against AI technology in general. I might look more favorable towards it in the future.
Creation of knowledge still makes sense and it's a worthwhile goal in itself, but the way it will be presented and generated and consumed will all change a lot from today. Adaptation to change in conditions is kind of normal but it needs to be the right adaptation.
In troubled times I would concentrate on quality. High quality is something not many people (or algorithms) can achieve. Only collaborations of humans supported by technology in a smart way can achieve that. Producing the highest quality Q&A might be a good argument for remaining relevant.
And maybe the human factor is also important. AI generated content cannot offer a human touch, the feeling that there is someone who really cares and enjoys the interaction. And the backside of it is human friction, the feeling that this is a really annoying place. Maybe the system can be designed a bit more towards the first. Can one strive for highest quality and still remain respectful and understanding all the time?
So, get your priorities right and start experimenting because ... not much to lose anyway. Present your data and listen to feedback. Formulate straight to the point. Tell us where you are going. Maybe then people will follow.
Anyway, posting here feels a bit like escapism, given that much, much more is going on in the world. I wish you luck with the continued development of the platform.

In a way - I think your answer hits several similar notes as Anerdw's; they aren't saying the same things, but they feel like different facets of the same issue. Or it could also be that my reading of his answer was colored by reading yours first :) - in either case, the issue is complex and connects to even more answers. (Bryan's on the worries about the broader internet, Tyler's on the money question, etc). I believe one of the key strengths we have is indeed the human factor - knowing that this is the product of human effort is great.

However, it is indeed also relevant to consider that the human factor can also be a breach of other peoples' expectations. Sometimes, humans aren't always respectful and understanding. Sometimes humans are harsh. Sometimes, people are tired of having to say the same thing all the time, and someone without the context gets lashed out at. This speaks to a need (as you called out) for onboarding but also for less being asked of curators. There is more to be handled before a human curator has to step in (not necessarily with GenAI).

The last minor point of interest to me is the matter of the data dump itself (it's even your nickname!). It is, by itself, a thing that makes it easier for the knowledge created by humans to be processed in the service of learning machines. I don't say this to say we should get rid of the data dump (I'm not trying to start that fire on December 17th). But - it does need to be recognized that an open internet makes it easier for mass consumption of content. It still may be worth having an open internet (I believe it is), but alas.

@CesarM Thanks for the comments. Regarding your last point, I'm not completely sure I understand correctly. You mention getting rid of the data dump and it being worth having an open internet, it's probably one or the other. The data dump has so many legitimate uses that contribute positively to say the further development of humankind, that shutting it down would be a great loss. If anything, the license of the data dump should prevent usage without attribution. But so far unfortunately it doesn't seem to. OpenAI and others may be freeloading there. This legal question should be solved.

@CesarM Regarding the human touch, comments (and maybe chat, not sure, don't really use chat) are a big part of it. This is where people do most of the interaction with each other. I wonder why the company never implemented comment threads, a feature often asked for. Maybe there is an actual reason that speaks against them, but maybe they also would have helped.

to clarify, what I mean is that, yeah, a data dump contributes to a free and open internet; I agree they go hand in hand. However, both of those do make it easier for the content to be consumed in a way/for a purpose that isn't intended/on par with those same goals of a free and open internet. I don't say this to mean that we should get rid of the dump, just that it's worth to acknowledge the abuse does exist, and there'll be a need to find some way to lessen it - it can be through legislation, for example, as you say.

As for the human touch, I agree true community building happens mostly on chat and other means of user communication that isn't necessarily main Q&A - though I don't think I understand how comment threads would help with that. I also think that community building through chat (and meta on this very question for example) isn't necessarily what I mean/understand by "Human touch" in the main Q&A - I mean more the knowledge there that the question and answers are created by actual humans to help actual humans, which isn't necessarily community, but is still a human touch.

It's not as is this question got too many answers (I remember Q&A with >100 answers), so I take the liberty of adding another one depicting the extremes (negative or positive) that I can think of. The truth will be somewhere in the middle, I guess. And it defines the axes on which we will move in one or the other direction.
Scenario A:
In 6-8 years, under immense pressure by big tech companies and politics (China would do it anyway, so we must too) the Supreme Court's final decision is that everything ever created by anyone or going to be created is all "fair" game and can be used for free to train AI. AI is widely used and started to create trillionaires when AI bots learned to put advertisements in their outputs (and finetuned on the ad efficiency). People stopped doing human Q&A and traditional services like all the Stack Exchanges got bought very soon. Even Wikipedia closed down eventually. StackOverflow is now simply the name of a somewhat popular bot. Creative people lost their jobs in masses, are now employed by big AI companies for little money and fix their products when AI doesn't hit the mark. It's the future of Q&A and everybody working in the industry (there aren't any volunteers) hates it. These workers are sometimes heard mumbling "Why didn't I go to the army, they pay decently at least." There are companies without any "traditional" employees simply driven by software, and they make billions. The Internet outside of social media or bots is a complete wasteland.
Scenario B:
In 6-8 years, after learning how much money AI companies made and how little traditional creatives were left with, the public put pressure on politics to change that. Finally a formula was found, where one can opt out of training easily and where AI companies must give the majority of their profits to those sources where they got their training data from. That saved (among many others) Q&A and made it a viable, however less thriving than in the past, business. A few companies (Stack Exchange could be among them) adapted best to the situation by concentrating on gathering new knowledge or improving the quality of existing knowledge or finding better structures for knowledge or emphasizing the human origin of their knowledge or letting their human users participating financially in their success or creating spaces where humans can interact in a guaranteed human environment but with access to modern technology. Those continued. Finally politics started taxing AI usage and a new equilibrium evolved, which most people were at least a little bit happy with.
Which one it will be or if it was something else instead, time will tell.

But, where is Stack Exchange in all of this?

@ShadowWizard Sorry, I thought it was more clear. In the first case it goes down no matter what and only the most relevant brand name survives, in the second case it also goes down unless it adapts and does one or multiple of the mentioned adaptations. That means it needs to be lucky and under the right circumstances finds a niche or it will cease to exist. Sounds almost trivial now, but still I tried to depict the range of possible futures as faithful as possible.

@ShadowWizard Stack Exchange went bankrupt in 2026 so it's not in the 6-8 years vision.

" Creative people lost their jobs in masses, are now employed by big AI companies for little money and fix their products when AI doesn't hit the mark" or instead these workers help educate kids, treat injured individuals and improve human longevity, instead of having tiktok kids and dying at 75.

@FranckDernoncourt "instead these workers help educate kids, treat injured individuals and improve human longevity" Only if they somehow can get paid for it, otherwise not. You have to live from something.

@NoDataDumpNoContribution There exist many solutions for that such as taxing automation eg https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robot_tax (or better, stop waging wars and reduce military budgets, but this is more difficult because of the appallingly poor education that we have received so far).

@FranckDernoncourt I agree that solutions exist, but that doesn't mean they will be implemented. Or they may be implemented but only after some prolonged transition period, which might still be bad for people living in it. And there are still many other problems. And maybe I'm just too pessimistic. I know an artist who is happy she is retired now. She says she lived in the golden time of art where you could make money from this profession. Others may be more optimistic there and see lots of opportunities for even greater things.

@NoDataDumpNoContribution  won't appear that golden when they'll die from some disease that could have been cured if people focused on finding treatments for those diseases instead of doing automatable jobs

As an optimist? Option 3. There's a big burst bubble over AI and manipulative social media. People go back to smaller, better natured, more intimate community. We can finally get around to trying to rebuild a happier space than what we have now :D

@JourneymanGeek doesn't sound optimistic to me as if  AI is just a big burst bubble then we lose our chance at having a much longer+healthier life.

On the contrary - Tech has survived burst bubbles before. This gives a chance to build tools from a more balanced footing than big promises made to extract maximum VC money .

@JourneymanGeek And history is littered with doomsayers (like me). But then again, the past is not a reliable predictor of the future. This time might be the time where things turn for better or worse. Who knows. Surely AI is a disruption and the real value is discussing along which axes this disruption will work and what people actually would prefer to have. A chance to build better tools we have had the whole time.

Personally, I’m most worried about the company’s actions, particularly in regard to AI and listening to the community.
There is now an AnswerBot on WebApps which was kept hidden from the community for months until it was accidentally leaked by posting AI answers.
I imagine said bot will soon start posting AI answers on WebApps intentionally. Then, the bot will likely be deemed successful there, no matter how bad the answers are or no matter the community thinks. It will then be moved on to flood other Stack Exchange sites.
With an AI answering every question in 30 seconds and the answers incredibly difficult to debunk, even though they are all wrong, StackExchange will become useless. Knowledgeable answerers will move somewhere else, and eventually so will the askers. If I wanted to ask my question to an LLM, I don’t need stack exchange for that.
Not only that, but you no longer listen to your community. Many if not most company posts (that aren’t fixing bugs or something like that) are very heavily downvoted. That’s bad and that didn’t use to happen. It means that the company is now out of touch with the community. We want different things, and the company seems to feel it can ignore the community.
This is very worrying, perhaps even more than the AnswerBot. As long as Stack Exchange listens to and values the community, I believe they will almost always arrive at reasonable decisions and generally not harm the site. But if they decide, as they seem to have, that the community is disposable, just a large data creation project for some LLM, I have no confidence this site won’t be destroyed.
The only thing that gives me hope, really, is last year’s strike. That was really the one time the company listened to the community. Sure, it took thousands of users, hundreds of mods, a 2 month long strike, and a lot of spam on the homepage, but StackExchange actually listened! That, if the community all works together, we actually can get through to the company. If Stack Exchange did something incredibly stupid tomorrow, and we all went on strike, I do think we could likely get through to them.

Respectfully, I can't help but notice that this answer was posted very quickly after posting; it speaks in strong absolutes and uses quite a lot of hyperbole. I understand that this style of answer plays well to the Meta Stack Exchange audience, and of course there is a reasonable kernel of truth to take away from the reactive answer. But I have to say, what I'm really interested in here is the long view, past this week's hot issue, with a bit more carefuly-considered nuance -- I wish you'd taken more time to consider the possible futures before sharing it here. (You still can.)

I was hoping we could see some answers that talk about the much larger picture and not focus so much on "just" AI. Most everyone is upset about AI. I'm upset about AI. You're not really saying anything new here. I'd encourage you to take some time to think about the bigger questions. "What are we?", "What do we want our future to look like?", "What (other) issues concern (me/us)?"

@Slate How was I hyperbolic? I do believe this is the long view, admittedly, not an optimistic one. I think AI and response to the community will be the main determines of Stack Exchange”s future

To be fair, @Slate I would instead say that you are severely undervaluing how long users have been felling like this. It should not take hours to know how you have been felling for month, so I don't think you can honestly handwave Starship answer by saying it came to soon. The issues some users seems so obsessed with "to speak in strong absolutes" aren't something that was born in the last few days. I have purposely avoided wasting time posting an answer here because I expected something like this, but it is not like I would have needed thinking for hours about what has been worrying me

@ꓢPArcheon Nah, I get it. I'm hardly oblivious to the pain - I read most of the salient discussions on Meta. I moderated the network for seven years. But, well - one way or another, to get to the nuance, the real meat of discussion, we're going to have to push through the reactive anger that causes people to speak in absolutes, to rush to find fault, to place quick and hard blame. I don't mean to be dismissive, and I hope it doesn't sound that way. I know where it comes from. But I don't plan to simply give up and go "well, folks are angry," and leave it at that. There's more to explore here.

it's not exactly true that staff posts haven't historically been negatively received when presenting changes... it's just there's far less quantity of staff posts that aren't that. CM's aren't quite as integrated into the public Q&A community as they were many years ago.

@KevinB That tends to happen when you fire them all

@KevinB Obviously some have but those were rare exceptions. Just about every super lower scored is from 2019 and onwards

But, @Slate, people aren't interested in yet another throwaway Meta Discussion. They want to see real actions, but those never arrive. It just feels like another stall.

@AndreascondemnsIsrael I respect that viewpoint. I know people have been burned in the past. At the same time, these aren't the sorts of problems that can be fixed without discussion and serious thought. Unless you want the future to be marked by a propensity towards guesswork. (I suppose you could believe that I could personally tell my managers "we shouldn't do AI" and they'll then go "oh, ok" and stop, but I think that's a little idealistic. A little bit of a deeper analysis of how we got here and where we're going is required.)

@Slate Ehm, there's already been an endless amount of discussion about this. There really isn't a need for any more. It only makes it harder to find a conclusion and an understanding. But, you do you, and people can choose to discuss on forever if they want to.

@KevinB I can't speak for others, but I'll clearly state, I interact on a number of different sites, but use my personal account when doing so - aside from the desire to keep my personal and work like separate, I also like getting interaction unclouded by whatever unintentional bias someone may have when they see a staff tag.

@Slate What is needed is that if you say to your managers “the community is really against X and make some good points, maybe we should reconsider”, they actually reconsider

@Dalmarus I’m talking about meta posts specifically on behalf of the company…the issues isn’t individual employees it’s stack management

@Starship They are reconsidering. The company management really really really really wants "a GenAI thing": the number of iterations we've been through, the amount of planning that's gone into this so far and it isn't even far enough along to receive public feedback because it's still got an axe hanging over it (the leak was accidental)… Not listening to us isn't the problem.

Not believing us, when we say "this cannot possibly work", is the problem: but there are always naysayers, so unless SE management have enough expertise to go "actually these theoretical CS arguments are sound, these ethical concerns are unmitigatable, and this economic analysis shows that the whole genre is either subsidised or unprofitable", they have no way of distinguishing us from overconfident sufferers of Nobel disease.

@Starship There was heavy and unprecedented consultation with moderators, which I will not talk about because it was in confidence.

@Starship Your memory of the reasons, goals, and outcomes of the strike don't really align with mine.


What do you look forward to?

I look forward to the day when AI fully replaces Stack Exchange and other human QA sites. I have asked thousands of questions here and it's always been a struggle to get informed without getting sucked into irrelevant and/or unhelpful discussions. Meanwhile, I've been using GPT for a while and nowadays on my own questions it matches or outperforms Stack Exchange about 20 to 30% of the time. When it does, it's a delight because it's faster and cheaper (even the 200 USD/month for ChatGPT Pro is bargain compared to the time wasted here).

about the future of the network

I think that Stack Exchange is bound to become a crowdsourcing platform for AI training data and will continue to lose traffic as AI continues to progressively replaces it, at least most of it (since most questions aren't about cutting edge information that the AI hasn't learned about yet).

I don't participate a lot more because of the trollish arguing. But you're taking an unreal view that many of the minds here can be replaced by AI; because none of the pull requests on the open source projects I use are made by AI, those humans are needed to lend they're expertise and it's nowhere on the horizon that AI can magically replace them. I understand you're active in research, let me ask you: how many researchers lacking integrity have you see sucking up grants to finance nonsense AI projects leading nowhere? I'd say: A LOT! So I'm not buying unless there's tangible return.

But you're right addressing the OP with the main issue that some SE communities are unreasonably argumentative, I agree with that assertion! AI won't magically solve those human/social/community issues, and here's where I take a different view: the persons/communities engaged in that negative culture need to be addressed and a tone should be set (SE never bothered with it). Removing the human factor isn't a solution (although it's often proposed in all sorts of contexts) and that kind of mindset should be consistently called out by addressing it as a mistake.

"I look forward to the day when AI fully replaces..." That day may not come for a long time. As you say we might be now at 20-30%, which still raises the question how to find out when AI is better and when it's worse, but typically the first steps in every project are the easiest and getting from half working to fully working and especially the last few percent working gets harder and harder.  In the current implementation, the performance of AI might level out at the some point.

@bad_coder LLMs can fix some bugs e.g. https://arxiv.org/abs/2409.10033 but we're indeed nowhere close AGI and I agree with you about some research BS.

There's nothing stopping someone from using AI fully over SE, and that's fine. In economics terms, for certain kinds of usage its a substitute good. The two things can co-exist separately.  I'd say SE's decline is due to longer term issues than genAI tho

@NoDataDumpNoContribution yes good points, I have no idea when and at which level current models will plateau. I'm tempted to repeat my dislike of the current Roomba by pointing that these harder questions are more likely to be deleted by Roomba, so SE is shooting itself in the foot by killing questions that are difficult for an AI to answer. But to their defense, they can only sell QA pairs to AI companies: questions without answers are by and large worthless from a financial standpoint aside from attracting a little bit of traffic.

@FranckDernoncourt good link, but basically they dumped 40 well-known algorithms with an atomic syntactic error that was then corrected by copy-pasting into place from the LLM's knowledge base. The authors of the article (while boasting the usual big name academic/professional credentials) don't know how to write proper docstrings - something that always gives me a good laugh since I'm an SME in said details. I really do enjoy the link :) (I was going to include one just like it from the American Computational Linguistic association but I'll refrain from doing so).

@bad_coder That's a good catch. For unseen test sets, I'm mostly impressed by GPT o3 results on the EpochAI Frontier Math benchmark (collection of unpublished, hard math problems: o3 scores 25% success rate on it). I don't know if there's an equivalent unseen test set for coding / bug fixes.

"..my dislike of the current Roomba by pointing that these harder questions are more likely to be deleted by Roomba.." There are hard and easy questions and there are good and bad questions and there are answerable and not yet answerable questions. We maybe didn't put enough effort in clear delineating them. In voting, we preferred the easy, answerable questions and ignored a bit the complex, good, not yet answerable ones.

@NoDataDumpNoContribution Yes exactly. Not necessarily complex, it can otherwise just be simple but niche. And sometimes it's answerable but the experts/people with similar interests aren't around to answer at the adequate time.

He​llo,
We're writing in reference to your Stack Overflow website:
https://stackoverflow.com/
You have frequently abused or derided members of your community. Please note that once you build a website where the community is an integral component of the site, the website relies upon the collective efforts of those who have contributed to that content. Answerers that are potentially useful to others should not be removed except under extraordinary circumstances. Even if the answers are no longer useful to the advertising department, that information is still beneficial to others who may run into similar problems in the future - this is the underlying philosophy of Stack Exchange.
Extensive lack of trust takes a lot of effort to repair; please read "My users don't like me; can I delete them?" for possible alternatives. Because of the amount of disruption these incidents can cause, we have placed your website on hold for 30 days while we reach out to you to avoid any further misunderstandings. Once this matter has been resolved, your reputation score will be restored and your website will resume as normal.
We sincerely hope this is just a misunderstanding, but we understand that you may have an exceptional reason to abuse this community. If so, let us know by replying to this message.
Regards,
Stack Overflow Corporation Management Team

Whilst amusing, I'm not sure how helpful this is.

Sure making a lot of comments for someone who doesn't want to share their honest opinion and considers themselves removed from the community.

As far as I can tell, Slate isn't really doing this as an Official Staff Member Of The Company Known As Stack Exchange Incorporated. This is a rare opportunity for extended discussion with somebody who cares about this community, is part of this community, and happens to have the ability to make things happen - do you really want to waste it on vitriol?

@Anerdw slate did this on work time for three days and was (presumably) given permission to do so. I take that as a good and even better thing.
